# Is it possible to split a sequence of numbers into two groups based in median value without sorting?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Is there an algorithm to split a sequence of random numbers into two groups based on a median value determined on the fly(without sorting them)?

Ex. If I have the sequence 2-3-6-7-1-4-5, the result would be two separated groups:

A) 1 2 3

B) 5 6 7

Median value: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done in **O(n)**.

First of all, if we already knew the median, we could easily split the sequence in two in **O(n)** by iterating the sequence and comparing each value with the median.  So how do we find the median in **O(n)**?

The basic idea is to use [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), but instead of recursively sorting both sides of the pivot, *only sort the half that contains the median* (ie. the half that encompasses the index `⌈n/2⌉`).  If our selection of a pivot guarantees geometric convergence of quicksort (like [median-of-medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_.22Median_of_Medians_algorithm.22) does), then our overall algorithm will be O(n).

### Algorithm

*Let's call the current size of our array **k**, and the reduction due to median-of-medians **c** - ie. our pivot guarantees the array shrinks by a factor of at least **c** each step*

1. Estimate the median of the array using median-of-medians - **O(k)**
2. Partition the array quicksort-style (with the estimate as our pivot) - **O(k)**
3. Choose the half of the array containing the median (index `⌈n/2⌉`).  This new sub-array will have size no greater than `k/c`.  Repeat steps 1 & 2 recursively until we've determined the element whose position in the original array is `⌈n/2⌉`.

The asymptotic running time of this algorithm is

**2 O(n) + 2 O(n/c) + 2 O(n/c<sup>2</sup>) + 2 O(n/c<sup>3</sup>) + ...**
= **O(n)**

Answer (score 3):

You can find the median of an array (and split) in [linear time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_.22Median_of_Medians_algorithm.22).

Comment: That algorithm will estimate the median in linear time, but is not guaranteed to give you the median...

Comment: It is guaranteed to give median exactly. For n=2k+1 take (k+1)-th element, for n=2k take average of k-th and (k+1)-th element.

Comment: @sdcvvc: Unfortunately, no, it's not.  Imagine the case of splitting the numbers 1-9 into thirds (instead of fifths, for simplicity):  if our groups are (1,2,6), (3,4,5), (7,8,9), the pivot chosen will be 4 (the median is 5).  The article itself admits the pivot is only guaranteed to be in the middle 40% (when splitting into 5ths).

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: The pivot is not the final result. The algorithm is run recursively on 7/10 of sequence.

Comment: Ah, I see, it mentions that above the section you linked.  In that case, it's the same as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The BFPRT (Blum-Floyd-Pratt-Rivest-Tarjan)-Algorithm (look at [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm)) can find the median in linear time, i.e. in `O(n)`.

However the constant "hidden" in the `O`-notation is so large that for practice it is faster to sort the array in `O(n log n)` for reasonable array sizes.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the median by finding the average between the floor(n/2)th largest item and the floor(n/2)th smallest item.  This can be done with help of this [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on).

After that, simply iterate through your array, putting elements greater than the median into one and lower than the median into the other.

---

Alternatively, if you knew the size of your sequence, you could create two collections of size floor(n/2): one "smallest half" (**S**) and one "largest half" (**L**), and then one by one by one:

- Take out one element in your sequence, call it **e**.
- Put it into **S** if **S** is not full.
- If **S** is full, find the largest element of (**S** | **e**) (the union of the two) (this can be impelemented by iterating through **S** until an element larger than **e** is found; if none is found, it is **e**, else, it is the found element), and add it to **L**.  If this largest was in **S**, put **e** in **S** to re-fill it.
- If **L** is full, find the smallest element of (**L** | **e**) and remove it, adding **e** into **L** if **e** was not removed.

I *believe* this is O(n) time; someone correct me if I'm wrong.  The worst case scenario I could imagine is the original sequence being sorted in descending order.

ruby implementation (with much un-performancy shortcuts):

```
def split_into_halves to_split
  s = []
  l = []
  medianlimit = to_split.size/2
  for e in to_split
    if s.size < medianlimit
      s.push(e)
    else

      if s.max >= n
        max = s.max
        s.delete max
        s.push(e)
      else
        max = e
      end

      if l.size < medianlimit
        l.push(max)
      elsif l.max >= max
        l.delete l.max
        l.push(max)
      end

    end
  end

  return [s,l]
end

k = [2,3,6,7,1,4,5]
split_into_halves(k) #=> [[2,3,1],[6,4,5]]
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess it is because you seem to be using a non-standard definition of median, and the main question which the OP has, you have dismissed by a link instead of saying use that... :-)

Comment: "iterating through S until an element larger than e is found" is going to be O(N), since S is half N in size. You need to do this for half of the elements, once S is full. So your algorithm is O(N squared)

Comment: Also, the answer you reference will not be O(N) as you are not working with a fixed k, but with k=n/2 to find the values you mention.