# Find the 2nd largest element in an array with minimum number of comparisons

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

For an array of size N, what is the number of comparisons required?

Comment: How much temporary storage are you allowed?

Comment: guess it will be (n-1) comparisons only. I am just thinking of sorting whole list and getting the second element from the list

Comment: @Sachin, it would be n*log(n) comparisons. Sorting cannot get faster.

Comment: @Stargazer712 - You are right. Unthoughtful of me. Thanks.

Comment: @Stargazer712: Unless the array is of integers. Then you could radix-sort, with no comparisons at all ;-)

Comment: @Steve: Even then, that assumes you know the lower and upper bounds on the integers :). Radix sort is very useful, but extremely constrained. When such constraints are not given in the problem, its best to assume n*log(n)

Comment: More generally, finding the k-th largest element: http://stackoverflow.com/q/251781/98654

Comment: @Stargazer712: No bounds needed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#In-place_MSD_radix_sort_implementations. Come to think of it, a radix sort still involves looping over the input data, and a loop has to involve a comparison in the termination condition. It needn't be an *order* comparison, though, just an equality comparison. But you're right, the question says nothing about the data types, so a proper answer has to assume opaque data and a comparator function. If the interviewer instead makes the mistake of posing an `int` special case (or string at a real push), it's 0 comparisons...

Comment: @Steve, that still assumes that you are not using a "long" datatype (in the case of python), or a BigInteger (in the case of C++) :). Radix sort is regretfully limited.

Comment: @Stargazer712: An LSD radix sort will handle big ints, although that's not what I linked to.

Comment: @Steve, Ah, but you are missing a problem present with 'long': the length is unrestrained. The complexity of radix sort is not O(n), it is O(d*n) where d is the number of digits. If the digits exceed the size of n, then you have performed worse than a O(n^2) sort :P. It doesn't matter. This is my final comment on the matter. Radix sort is useful, but constrained ;)

Comment: @Stargazer712: sure, but the question isn't, "do this in the lowest possible complexity time", it's "do it in the least possible number of comparisons". 0 comparisons would win if possible, even if it's O(A(d,n)) *time* (A the Ackermann function) ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop why do you use Ackermann function? (I searched about it, but couldn't find out why you used it in time complexity concept) :)

Comment: I found this(http://www.ajaybadgujar.com/finding-second-largest-number-from-array-in-javascript/) solution very useful  with minimal complexity

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The optimal algorithm uses n+log n-2 comparisons. Think of elements as competitors, and a tournament is going to rank them.

First, compare the elements, as in the tree

```
   |
  / \
 |   |
/ \ / \
x x x x
```

this takes n-1 comparisons and each element is involved in comparison at most log n times. You will find the largest element as the winner.

The second largest element must have lost a match to the winner (he can't lose a match to a different element), so he's one of the log n elements the winner has played against. You can find which of them using log n - 1 comparisons.

The optimality is proved via adversary argument. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601 or http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/497/02-selection.pdf or  http://www.imada.sdu.dk/~jbj/DM19/lb06.pdf or https://www.utdallas.edu/~chandra/documents/6363/lbd.pdf

Comment: Query: this will take N + logN -2 comparisons in addition to the initial N - 1 comparisons needed to find the maximum, right? Because without knowing the maximum, how can we know the logN elements that lost a match against the winner.

Comment: @Jatin: No, it takes N+log N-2 in total: N-1 comparisons to find the maximum, and log N-1 comparisons to find the largest element among the log N that lost to the maximal element.

Comment: how do I find those logN elements? I can't do that by simply traversing the array while trying to find the maximum.

Comment: Jatin: create a binary tree, and start filling it from the bottom. The leaves are elements of the array. Each internal vertex is maximum of its two children. The number of comparisons you need is the number of internal vertices, which is n-1. Then, look at the "opponents" of the maximal element, those are the log N elements.

Comment: So this involves some space complexity and that answers everything to me :)

Comment: @Sreekar: This algorithm requires extra space, I don't know if there's one that does not and still uses N + log N - 2 comparisons.

Comment: @sdcvvc There isn't.. as far as I know. I found this question in textbook "Introduction to Algorithms" and thought we shouldn't use extra space and tried so hard to get an algorithm.

Comment: @sdcvvc : upvoted your answer, a very nice explanation. One more query, if we need to find 3rd maximum, then it will have           n + 3logn -8. Can You explain me how. ?

Comment: @sdcvvc : I tried to do it the way you explained but I am not able understand, how do we get 3 logn term ?

Comment: @POOJA GUPTA: First, find the largest and 2nd largest element (as in my answer); that gives one logn term. The 3rd largest element must have lost either to the 1st or the 2nd one, so you need to check elements which lost the comparison to 1st greatest element (that's the second logn term) and to 2nd greatest element (that's the third logn term).

Comment: @POOJAGUPTA : where did you get this number "n + 3logn -8" for finding 3rd maximum? I searched a lot, but couldn't find anything related to this number.

Comment: @sdcvvc : thank you for your great explanation! May I ask you how you justify the "8" in this "n + 3logn -8" number of comparison for 3rd maximum?

Comment: @Hengameh to be honest I don't see the reason for the 8. It takes (n + log n - 2) comparisons to find largest and second largest element, call them L_1 and L_2; next, we find the largest element that lost to L_1, which is not L_2, there are log n-1 candidates for this, which means log n-2 comparisons, next, we find the largest element that lost to L_2, there are log n-2 candidates, so log n-3 comparisons, take the max of those two, this gives n+log n-2 + log n - 2 + log n - 3 + 1=n+3 log n-6. I might be missing something though, the logarithms should be under ceilings etc.

Comment: `n+log n-2 comparisons … The optimality is proved via adversary argument` - funny considering handing down max candidates needs n-1 comparisons.

Comment: Can't I just create a Max Heap which will have at most (n-1) comparisons for creation of the whole heap tree. And then the root is the largest and max child of the root is 2nd largest. Overall n-1+1=n comparisons??

Comment: @dark_passenger It's not possible to create a heap using n-1 comparisons. (The usual algorithm needs 2n-O(log n) comparisons.) As I said in the answer, there is actually no method that takes less than n+log n-2 comparisons and uses only comparisons.

Answer (score 12):

You can find the second largest value with at most 2·(*N*-1) comparisons and two variables that hold the largest and second largest value:

```
largest := numbers[0];
secondLargest := null
for i=1 to numbers.length-1 do
    number := numbers[i];
    if number > largest then
        secondLargest := largest;
        largest := number;
    else
        if number > secondLargest then
            secondLargest := number;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: How do you find 2 largest elements in a set of 3 using 2 comparisons?

Comment: @sdcvvc: Yes, but I guess he’s aiming for the complexity. And that’s O(*N*).

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't work for {1,3,2}. It would return 1 instead of 2.

Comment: -1. Your algorithm does not work. Try it on the input "3,5,4".

Comment: doesn't work. You can't find the second largest if your second largest is before the largest.

Comment: @WilsonSoetheCursino give an example. I can see it does work. Here's PHP version of the algorithm: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/51e1b05dac2e648fd13e0b60f44a2abe1e4a8689

Comment: Wrong: you are missing a condition in else part. Where you have to compare digit from array if it is greater than the second_largest and also less than the current largest_number. My Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47029142/2695445

Answer (score 11):

Use Bubble sort or Selection sort algorithm which sorts the array in descending order. Don't sort the array completely. Just two passes. First pass gives the largest element and second pass will give you the second largest element.

No. of comparisons for first pass: n-1

No. of comparisons for second pass: n-2

Total no. of comparison for finding second largest: 2n-3

May be you can generalize this algorithm. If you need the 3rd largest then you make 3 passes.

By above strategy you don't need any temporary variables as Bubble sort and Selection sort are [in place sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16585507/465053) algorithms.

Comment: this is really clever solution

Comment: I am curious about the time complexity of this solution, as one loop will execute only two times.

Comment: My solution is also `2n-3`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code that might not be optimal but at least actually finds the 2nd largest element:

```
if( val[ 0 ] > val[ 1 ] )
{
    largest = val[ 0 ]
    secondLargest = val[ 1 ];
}
else
{
    largest = val[ 1 ]
    secondLargest = val[ 0 ];
}

for( i = 2; i < N; ++i )
{
    if( val[ i ] > secondLargest )
    {
        if( val[ i ] > largest )
        {
            secondLargest = largest;
            largest = val[ i ];
        }
        else
        {
            secondLargest = val[ i ];
        }
    }
}
```

It needs at least N-1 comparisons if the largest 2 elements are at the beginning of the array and at most 2N-3 in the worst case (one of the first 2 elements is the smallest in the array).

Answer (score 1):

case 1-->9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
case 2--> 50 10 8 25 ........
case 3--> 50 50 10 8 25.........
case 4--> 50 50 10 8 50 25.......

```
public void second element()  
{
      int a[10],i,max1,max2;  
      max1=a[0],max2=a[1];  
      for(i=1;i<a.length();i++)  
      {  
         if(a[i]>max1)  
          {
             max2=max1;  
             max1=a[i];  
          }  
         else if(a[i]>max2 &&a[i]!=max1)  
           max2=a[i];  
         else if(max1==max2)  
           max2=a[i];  
      }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, JS code...

Tested with the two inputs:

```
a = [55,11,66,77,72];
a = [ 0, 12, 13, 4, 5, 32, 8 ];

var first = Number.MIN_VALUE;
var second = Number.MIN_VALUE;
for (var i = -1, len = a.length; ++i < len;) {
    var dist = a[i];
    // get the largest 2
    if (dist > first) {
        second = first;
        first = dist;
    } else if (dist > second) { // && dist < first) { // this is actually not needed, I believe
        second = dist;
    }
}

console.log('largest, second largest',first,second);
largest, second largest 32 13
```

This should have a maximum of a.length*2 comparisons and only goes through the list once.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but here is my attempt at solving it, making use of the Tournament Algorithm. It is similar to the solution used by @sdcvvc , but I am using two-dimensional array to store elements.

To make things work, there are two assumptions:
1) number of elements in the array is the power of 2
2) there are no duplicates in the array

The whole process consists of two steps:
 1. building a 2D array by comparing two by two elements. First row in the 2D array is gonna be the entire input array. Next row contains results of the comparisons of the previous row. We continue comparisons on the newly built array and keep building the 2D array until an array of only one element (the largest one) is reached.
 2. we have a 2D-array where last row contains only one element: the largest one. We continue going from the bottom to the top, in each array finding the element that was "beaten" by the largest and comparing it to the current "second largest" value. To find the element beaten by the largest, and to avoid O(n) comparisons, we must store the index of the largest element in the previous row. That way we can easily check the adjacent elements. At any level (above root level),the adjacent elements are obtained as:

```
leftAdjacent = rootIndex*2
rightAdjacent = rootIndex*2+1,
```

where rootIndex is index of the largest(root) element at the previous level.

I know the question asks for C++, but here is my attempt at solving it in Java. (I've used lists instead of arrays, to avoid messy changing of the array size and/or unnecessary array size calculations)

```
public static Integer findSecondLargest(List<Integer> list) {
        if (list == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (list.size() == 1) {
            return list.get(0);
        }
        List<List<Integer>> structure = buildUpStructure(list);
        System.out.println(structure);
        return secondLargest(structure);

    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> buildUpStructure(List<Integer> list) {
        List<List<Integer>> newList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        List<Integer> tmpList = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
        newList.add(tmpList);
        int n = list.size();
        while (n>1) {
            tmpList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i<n; i=i+2) {
                Integer i1 = list.get(i);
                Integer i2 = list.get(i+1);
                tmpList.add(Math.max(i1, i2));
            }
            n/= 2;
            newList.add(tmpList);   
            list = tmpList;
        }
        return newList;
    }

    public static Integer secondLargest(List<List<Integer>> structure) {
        int n = structure.size();
        int rootIndex = 0;
        Integer largest = structure.get(n-1).get(rootIndex);
        List<Integer> tmpList = structure.get(n-2);
        Integer secondLargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        Integer leftAdjacent = -1;
        Integer rightAdjacent = -1;
        for (int i = n-2; i>=0; i--) {
            rootIndex*=2;
            tmpList = structure.get(i);
            leftAdjacent = tmpList.get(rootIndex);
            rightAdjacent = tmpList.get(rootIndex+1); 
            if (leftAdjacent.equals(largest)) {
                if (rightAdjacent > secondLargest) {
                    secondLargest = rightAdjacent;
                }
            }
            if (rightAdjacent.equals(largest)) {
                if (leftAdjacent > secondLargest) {
                    secondLargest = leftAdjacent;
                }
                rootIndex=rootIndex+1;
            }
        }

        return secondLargest;
    }
```

Comment: Borrowed your solution here - http://k2code.blogspot.in/2014/03/find-out-largest-and-second-largest.html. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose provided array is  inPutArray = [1,2,5,8,7,3] expected O/P -> 7 (second largest)

```
 take temp array 
      temp = [0,0], int dummmy=0;
    for (no in inPutArray) {
    if(temp[1]<no)
     temp[1] = no
     if(temp[0]<temp[1]){
    dummmy = temp[0]
    temp[0] = temp[1]
    temp[1] = temp
      }
    }

    print("Second largest no is %d",temp[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP version of the Gumbo algorithm: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/51e1b05dac2e648fd13e0b60f44a2abe1e4a8689

```
$numbers = [10, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

$largest = $numbers[0];
$secondLargest = null;
for ($i=1; $i < count($numbers); $i++) {
    $number = $numbers[$i];
    if ($number > $largest) {
        $secondLargest = $largest;
        $largest = $number;
    } else if ($number > $secondLargest) {
        $secondLargest = $number;
    }
}

echo "largest=$largest, secondLargest=$secondLargest";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming space is irrelevant, this is the smallest I could get it. It requires 2*n comparisons in worst case, and n comparisons in best case:

```
arr = [ 0, 12, 13, 4, 5, 32, 8 ]
max = [ -1, -1 ]

for i in range(len(arr)):
     if( arr[i] > max[0] ):
        max.insert(0,arr[i])
     elif( arr[i] > max[1] ):
        max.insert(1,arr[i])

print max[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use counting sort and then find the second largest element, starting from index 0 towards the end. There should be  at least 1 comparison, at most `n-1` (when there's only one element!).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about the number of comparisons. The question is for analysis of an algorithm, not just the algorithm itself.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
max1 = a[0].
max2.
for i = 0, until length:
  if a[i] > max:
     max2 = max1.
     max1 = a[i].
     #end IF
  #end FOR
return min2.
```

it should work like a charm. low in complexity.

here is a java code.

```
int secondlLargestValue(int[] secondMax){
int max1 = secondMax[0]; // assign the first element of the array, no matter what, sorted or not.
int max2 = 0; // anything really work, but zero is just fundamental.
   for(int n = 0; n < secondMax.length; n++){ // start at zero, end when larger than length, grow by 1. 
        if(secondMax[n] > max1){ // nth element of the array is larger than max1, if so.
           max2 = max1; // largest in now second largest,
           max1 = secondMax[n]; // and this nth element is now max.
        }//end IF
    }//end FOR
    return max2;
}//end secondLargestValue()
```

Comment: It is not efficient in number of comparison! you scan the whole array, I think the number of comparison is n!

Comment: and your code is not correct as well! what if "secondmax[n] > max2"? You didn't check this probability!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
        int a[5] = {55,11,66,77,72};
        int max,min,i;
        int smax,smin;
        max = min = a[0];
        smax = smin = a[0];
        for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
        {
                if(a[i]>max)
                {
                        smax = max;
                        max = a[i];
                }
                if(max>a[i]&&smax<a[i])
                {
                        smax = a[i];
                }
        }
        printf("the first max element z %d\n",max);
        printf("the second max element z %d\n",smax);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution by sdcvvc in C++11.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <climits>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::random_shuffle;
using std::min;
using std::max;

vector<int> create_tournament(const vector<int>& input) {
  // make sure we have at least two elements, so the problem is interesting
  if (input.size() <= 1) {
    return input;
  }

  vector<int> result(2 * input.size() - 1, -1);

  int i = 0;
  for (const auto& el : input) {
    result[input.size() - 1 + i] = el;
    ++i;
  }

  for (uint j = input.size() / 2; j > 0; j >>= 1) {
    for (uint k = 0; k < 2 * j; k += 2) {
      result[j - 1 + k / 2] = min(result[2 * j - 1 + k], result[2 * j + k]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

int second_smaller(const vector<int>& tournament) {
  const auto& minimum = tournament[0];
  int second = INT_MAX;

  for (uint j = 0; j < tournament.size() / 2; ) {
    if (tournament[2 * j + 1] == minimum) {
      second = min(second, tournament[2 * j + 2]);
      j = 2 * j + 1;
    }
    else {
      second = min(second, tournament[2 * j + 1]);
      j = 2 * j + 2;
    }
  }

  return second;
}

void print_vector(const vector<int>& v) {
  for (const auto& el : v) {
    cout << el << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}

int main() {

  vector<int> a;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 2048; ++i)
    a.push_back(i);

  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    random_shuffle(a.begin(), a.end());
    const auto& v = create_tournament(a);
    assert (second_smaller(v) == 2);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through all the posts above but I am convinced that the implementation of the Tournament algorithm is the best approach. Let us consider the following algorithm posted by @Gumbo

```
largest := numbers[0];
secondLargest := null
for i=1 to numbers.length-1 do
    number := numbers[i];
    if number > largest then
        secondLargest := largest;
        largest := number;
    else
        if number > secondLargest then
            secondLargest := number;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

It is very good in case we are going to find the second largest number in an array. It has (2n-1) number of comparisons. But what if you want to calculate the third largest number  or some kth largest number. The above algorithm doesn't work. You got to another procedure.

So, I believe tournament algorithm approach is the best and here is the [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/malkit/entry/finding_kth_minimum_partial_ordering) for that.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution would take 2(N-1) comparisons:

```
arr  #array with 'n' elements
first=arr[0]
second=-999999  #large negative no
i=1
while i is less than length(arr):
    if arr[i] greater than first:
        second=first
        first=arr[i]
    else:
        if arr[i] is greater than second and arr[i] less than first:
            second=arr[i]
    i=i+1
print second
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in n + ceil(log n) - 2 comparison.

Solution:
it takes n-1 comparisons to get minimum.

But to get minimum we will build a tournament in which each element will be grouped in pairs. like a tennis tournament and winner of any round will go forward.

Height of this tree will be log n since we half at each round.

Idea to get second minimum is that it will be beaten by minimum candidate in one of previous round. So, we need to find minimum in potential candidates (beaten by minimum).

Potential candidates will be log n = height of tree

So, no. of comparison to find minimum using tournament tree is n-1
and for second minimum is log n -1
sums up = n + ceil(log n) - 2

Here is C++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int,int> ii;

bool isPowerOfTwo (int x)
{
  /* First x in the below expression is for the case when x is 0 */
  return x && (!(x&(x-1)));
}
// modified
int log_2(unsigned int n) {
    int bits = 0;
    if (!isPowerOfTwo(n))
        bits++;
    if (n > 32767) {
        n >>= 16;
        bits += 16;
    }
    if (n > 127) {
        n >>= 8;
        bits += 8;
    }
    if (n > 7) {
        n >>= 4;
        bits += 4;
    }
    if (n > 1) {
        n >>= 2;
        bits += 2;
    }
    if (n > 0) {
        bits++;
    }
    return bits;
}

int second_minima(int a[], unsigned int n) {

    // build a tree of size of log2n in the form of 2d array
    // 1st row represents all elements which fights for min
    // candidate pairwise. winner of each pair moves to 2nd
    // row and so on
    int log_2n = log_2(n);
    long comparison_count = 0;
    // pair of ints : first element stores value and second
    //                stores index of its first row
    ii **p = new ii*[log_2n];
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0, j = n; i < log_2n; i++) {
        p[i] = new ii[j];
        j = j&1 ? j/2+1 : j/2;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        p[0][i] = make_pair(a[i], i);



    // find minima using pair wise fighting
    for (i = 1, j = n; i < log_2n; i++) {
        // for each pair
        for (k = 0; k+1 < j; k += 2) {
            // find its winner
            if (++comparison_count && p[i-1][k].first < p[i-1][k+1].first) {
                p[i][k/2].first = p[i-1][k].first;
                p[i][k/2].second = p[i-1][k].second;
            }
            else {
                p[i][k/2].first = p[i-1][k+1].first;
                p[i][k/2].second = p[i-1][k+1].second;
            }

        }
        // if no. of elements in row is odd the last element
        // directly moves to next round (row)
        if (j&1) {
            p[i][j/2].first = p[i-1][j-1].first;
            p[i][j/2].second = p[i-1][j-1].second;
        }
        j = j&1 ? j/2+1 : j/2;
    }



    int minima, second_minima;
    int index;
    minima = p[log_2n-1][0].first;
    // initialize second minima by its final (last 2nd row)
    // potential candidate with which its final took place
    second_minima = minima == p[log_2n-2][0].first ? p[log_2n-2][1].first : p[log_2n-2][0].first;
    // minima original index
    index = p[log_2n-1][0].second;
    for (i = 0, j = n; i <= log_2n - 3; i++) {
        // if its last candidate in any round then there is
        // no potential candidate
        if (j&1 && index == j-1) {
            index /= 2;
            j = j/2+1;
            continue;
        }
        // if minima index is odd, then it fighted with its index - 1
        // else its index + 1
        // this is a potential candidate for second minima, so check it
        if (index&1) {
            if (++comparison_count && second_minima > p[i][index-1].first)
                second_minima = p[i][index-1].first;
        }
        else {
            if (++comparison_count && second_minima > p[i][index+1].first)
                second_minima = p[i][index+1].first;
        }
        index/=2;
        j = j&1 ? j/2+1 : j/2;
    }


    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Minimum          : %d\n", minima);
    printf("Second Minimum   : %d\n", second_minima);
    printf("comparison count : %ld\n", comparison_count);
    printf("Least No. Of Comparisons (");
    printf("n+ceil(log2_n)-2) : %d\n", (int)(n+ceil(log(n)/log(2))-2));
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int n;
    scanf("%u", &n);
    int a[n];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    second_minima(a,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findSecondLargeNumber(arr){

    var fLargeNum = 0;
    var sLargeNum = 0;

    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(fLargeNum < arr[i]){
            sLargeNum = fLargeNum;
            fLargeNum = arr[i];         
        }else if(sLargeNum < arr[i]){
            sLargeNum = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return sLargeNum;

}
var myArray = [799, -85, 8, -1, 6, 4, 3, -2, -15, 0, 207, 75, 785, 122, 17];
```

Ref: http://www.ajaybadgujar.com/finding-second-largest-number-from-array-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

A good way with O(1) time complexity would be to use a max-heap. Call the heapify twice and you have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] int_array = {4, 6, 2, 9, 1, 7, 4, 2, 9, 0, 3, 6, 1, 6, 8};
    int largst=int_array[0];
    int second=int_array[0];
    for (int i=0; i<int_array.length; i++){        
        if(int_array[i]>largst) { 
            second=largst;
            largst=int_array[i];
        }  
        else if(int_array[i]>second  &&  int_array[i]<largst) { 
            second=int_array[i];
        } 
    }
```

Comment: everyone is missing that second condition in else part. Where you compare digit from array if it is greater than the second_largest and also less than the current largest_number.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, follow the "optimal algorithm uses n+log n-2 comparisons" from above, the code that I came up with that doesn't use binary tree to store the value would be the following:

During each recursive call, the array size is cut in half.

So the number of comparison is:

1st iteration: n/2 comparisons

2nd iteration: n/4 comparisons

3rd iteration: n/8 comparisons

...
Up to log n iterations?

Hence, total => n - 1 comparisons?

```
function findSecondLargestInArray(array) {
    let winner = [];
    if (array.length === 2) {
        if (array[0] < array[1]) {
            return array[0];
        } else {
            return array[1];
        }
    }
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
        if (array[2 * i - 1] > array[2 * i - 2]) {
            winner.push(array[2 * i - 1]);
        } else {
            winner.push(array[2 * i - 2]);
        }
    }
    return findSecondLargestInArray(winner);
}
```

Assuming array contain 2^n number of numbers.

If there are 6 numbers, then 3 numbers will move to the next level, which is not right.

Need like 8 numbers => 4 number => 2 number => 1 number => 2^n number of number

Answer (score -2):

```
package com.array.orderstatistics;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class SecondLargestElement {

    /**
     *  Total Time Complexity will be n log n + O(1)
     * @param str
     */
    public static void main(String str[]) {
        Integer[] integerArr = new Integer[] { 5, 1, 2, 6, 4 };



        // Step1 : Time Complexity will be n log(n)
        Arrays.sort(integerArr, Collections.reverseOrder());

        // Step2 : Array.get Second largestElement
        int secondLargestElement = integerArr[1];

        System.out.println(secondLargestElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the bit where you count the number of comparisons.  (Hint: there's quite a few hidden in the call to `Arrays.sort()`).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have corrected the code now. 
Arrays.sort(int[] a) in recent JDK is implemented with Dual-pivot Quicksort algorithm which has O(n log n) average complexity and is performed in-place (e.g. requires no extra space). So the total time complexity of this program will be O(n log n) + O(1).

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code! It will be much easier to understand when you do.

Answer (score -3):

Sort the array into ascending order then assign a variable to the (n-1)th term.

Comment: Very inefficient. Requires n*log(n) comparisons by definition.

Comment: Use brute force or tournament method, in brute force first comparison will take n-1 and on deleting the largesT, second will take n-2 = n-1 + n-2 = 2n-3 comparison with O(1) and T(1). With tournament you need to make sure there are element with power of 2 else add additional numbers to array and comparison will reduce to n + logn - 2 (logn creating tournament and n-1 for finding the largest among who lost to largest in tournament)