# details of finding 2nd smallest element in unsorted array

Tags: c++

Let me make things clear:
I want to know more about the implementation of the "best" ALGORITHM how to find 2nd smallest element in array, which is described here:

### [Algorithm: Find index of 2nd smallest element from an unknown array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715935/algorithm-find-index-of-2nd-smallest-element-from-an-unknown-array)

First, I am completely clear about the ALGORITHM how to find 2nd smallest element in array. 
The best solution is O(n+lg(n)-2) which can be achieved by first obtaining the smallest element S and then searching the smallest element of S's competitors. Read here:
[Algorithm: Find index of 2nd smallest element from an unknown array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715935/algorithm-find-index-of-2nd-smallest-element-from-an-unknown-array)

What I cannot understand is how to implement it.

Especially, after finding the smallest element, how to track back those competitors of the smallest element such that I can find 2nd smallest element in those competitors?

---

### NO NEED TO SORT. Quicksort is O(nlg(n)) which is worse than  O(n+lg(n)-2).

There have been too many people talking about the best solution while nobody actually gave an implementation. Besides, I found the best solution is just theoretical best. It is very hard to implement it following that "best" solution.

Comment: With respect, then it sounds like you are not completely clear on the algorithm.

Comment: Which way do you want to sort it? Quicksort? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: If you sort the array to find the smallest element, you can just go to the appropriate index of the array to get the smallest, either index 1 or (n-1)-1 where n is the number that you put for the size of the array.

Comment: @anon: No need to sort. This can be done in O(n).

Comment: @Fred Larson... O(n) on average you mean, right?

Comment: @Chris: no, this can be done in one pass and O(1) memory

Comment: @Chris: O(n) can be guaranteed for the worst case, indeed, not just in average.

Comment: @Chris A.: I mean O(n) exactly, as Andrei said.

Answer (score 3):

```
int smallest, secondsmallest;
if (array[0] < array[1]) {
    smallest = array[0];
    secondsmallest = array[1];
} else {
    smallest = array[1];
    secondsmallest = array[0];
}
for(int i = 2; i < array_size; i++) {
    if (array[i] < smallest) {
        secondsmallest = smallest;
        smallest = array[i];
    } else if (array[i] < secondsmallest) {
        secondsmallest = array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method is O(n^2).
Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715935/algorithm-find-index-of-2nd-smallest-element-from-an-unknown-array

Comment: @deryk: I quite clearly only loop through the array once. That makes it kind of impossible for my algorithm to be O(n^2).

Comment: Sorry, your algorithm is 2N > n+lg(n)-2

Comment: @deryk: You should brush up on complexity analysis. O(n) is the same as O(n + lgn -2), because you are only concerned with asymtotic behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Odd that no one has bothered to give this its name. Including the original questioner. For those unfamiliar with it, it is called the *i* th order statistic, and is discussed in many fine algorithm books. It is indeed O(n) (actually theta of n) for n elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the running "candidates" (and maybe number of their occurrences, depending on your strict definition of "2nd") for the smallest and second smallest value all along the way.

Comment: I can't find it in my heart to -1 this but we really shouldn't do this for homework problems...

Comment: @Andrei: I assume my hint is not too strong, why?

Comment: It is not actually a homework. There have been too many people talking about the best solution while nobody actually gave an implementation. Besides, I found the best solution is just theoretical best. It is very hard to implement it following that "best" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you kind of answered your own question:

1. How do you keep track of the
   smallest element? You store an index
   to it.
2. How do you find the second
   smallest element? Search again and
   ignore the element you found first.

Comment: That is not the best solution. The best one is to find the smallest element first and then find the 2nd smallest one by comparing competitors of the found smallest element.

Comment: @deryk, if you are asking for the "optimal" solution, you could probably do worse than looking at the implementation of `nth_element(...)` in the C++ STL. That is O(n), assuming you can mutate the array in place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should work

```
min1 = a[0]; 
min2 = 0;
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
   if (min1 < a[i]){
      min2 = min1;
      min1 = a[i];
   }
}
```

`a.length` is a Java instance of array. I'm not sure if C++ has the same one.

Comment: the c++ vector has a **.size()**

Comment: Wow, how is wrong answer like this get undetected for so long?
try [110, 10, 20, 120]

Answer (score 0):

```
// A simple implementation with O(n) runtime complexity;
int findSecondMin(vector<int>& nums) {
    if (nums.size() < 2) throw runtime_error("no second minimum !");
    int min1 = nums[0], min2 = INT_MAX;
    for(int i=1;i<nums.size();i++) {
      if (nums[i] < min1) {
        min2 = min1;
        min1 = nums[i];
      } else if (nums[i] < min2) {
        min2 = nums[i];
      }
    }
    return min2;
}
```