# How to find the index of second largest element in an array collection?

Tags: c++

I have a function which calculates sum of money spent on each checkout on a counter, After calculation, i want to find the best two checkout counter, I am able to find the index of the largest checkout, but I have a small confusion regarding finding the second largest checkout counter.
Here's the code.

```
for (int j = 0; j < Bq[i]; j++)
{
    sumM += p.GetValue(i, j).GetSum();
    sumT += p.GetValue(i, j).GetTime();
}
indexofmax = i;
if(sumM > maxmoney)
{
    Secondbestcheckout=firstbestcheckout;
    firstbestcheckout = indexofmax+1;
    maxmoney = sumM;
    secondindex = Secondbestcheckout;
    indexofmax =firstbestcheckout;
}
fr << i+1 << fixed << setw(9) << setprecision(2) << sumM
   << " " << setw(6) << sumT << endl;
}
fr << "The first best checkout interms of money collected is "
   << firstbestcheckout << "And the second best checkout is "
   <<  secondindex << endl;
```

This code is successful in printing the index of largest checkout counter, but not successful in printing the index of second largest.

Comment: This is my first post here, I didnt know to play with tools.

Comment: I see you are new. Welcome! I wasn't bashing at you, I just found it interesting how your bad indentation is still readable :). You'll get used to the tolls, don't worry.

Comment: It look like an easy problem with a complex solution. you are missing a lot of relevant code. I can't see, for example, how `i` is the index when  there is no iteration on it. try to give all the relevant code, but only the relevant code.

Comment: There is an extra foor loop above with i, and that I value is catched by bq[i]

Answer (score 1):

The second best is not sent only when you outperform the best.

Example with 40, 60, 50, 30

With your code, the fist time you set a best, is with 40.  Then 60 replaces it an 40 becomes the second best.  THen 50 arrives but it doesn't outperform the best so gets ignored as second best.

You have to add an clause, to handle this case:

```
...
if (sumM > maxmoney)   // as you already did
{
    Secondbestcheckout=firstbestcheckout;
    firstbestcheckout = indexofmax+1;
    secondmaxmoney = maxmoney;   // <<NEW INSTRUCTION - of course, you'll need to create and init secondmaxmoney somewhere ;-)
    maxmoney = sumM;
    secondindex = Secondbestcheckout;
    indexofmax =firstbestcheckout;
}
else if (sumM > secondmaxmoney)       // NEW STATEMENT  
{
    Secondbestcheckout= ...;       // as above, but unclear for me what the difference with secondinex is
    secondmaxmoney = maxmoney;     // update amount onf second best
    secondindex = i;               // or i+1 ?  Not clear if you start from 0 or from 1 
}
...  // rest or your code
```

Comment: I dont quite understand the code, can you  write the code w.r.t to my problem.

Comment: @NooruNizu I've completed the code. As I don't have the meaning of all your variables, I still have a doubt about secondbestchekedout and firstbestcheckedout, as in the printing you suggest these are amounts, but they are clearly copied from indexes to which you add 1.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make it complicated, it is simple:

```
INDX = (-ARRAY).argsort()[:N]
```

where N is the number of elements you are searching for, e.g. N=2 (two largest numbers)
ARRAY is your numpy array which you are searching in, e.g. ARRAY=np.array[10.1,9,10,5,1,3]
and, INDX is a list of the indices of the elements within the ARRAY. Obviously the length of INDX is equal to N.

Comment: May I know how NumPy is applicable in a C++ question?

Comment: You can use a better language

Answer (score 0):

If you can keep all the values in memory (i.e. if you have fewer than billions of checkouts), you can either use [`std::partial_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) to sort the two largest elements (but leave the rest unsorted), or you can use [`std::nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) twice, once with 1 and once with 2. (In both cases, your predicate should be `std::greater`, I suppose.)

If you need to process the values in a streaming fashion (i.e. with constant space), then you'll need to keep track of each order index separately, essentially similar to what you're attempting already. Boost.Accumulators may have some tools to simplify that task.