# Find the Max and 4th Max element

Tags: arrays, comparison, big-o, minmax

To find the maximum and 4th Maximum of an array what is the minimum number of comparisons needed? I assume I have to use an algorithm similar to MinMax and the solution found here:

[Find the 2nd largest element in an array with minimum number of comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628718/find-the-2nd-largest-element-in-an-array-with-minimum-number-of-comparisons)\

But I'm not sure how i would adapt the tournament style to this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question...

I think the trick is just to run the tournament a 2nd time, but with the largest and 2nd largest removed from the set (as determined by tournament #1).

Tournament #1:  To find in (1) [The largest] and in (2) [The 2nd largest]

Tournament #2:  With (1) and (2) removed from the set.  To find in (3) [The largest] and in (4) [The 2nd largest].  These will be the 3rd and 4th largest (respectively) from the original set.

1. n - 1
2. log n - 1
3. (n-2) - 1
4. log (n-2) - 1

[Edit]: I had better attempt some maths for completeness.

(1) + (2) + (3) + (4)

=> (n - 1) + (log n - 1) + ((n - 2) - 1) + (log (n-2) - 1)

=> 2n + (log n) + (log (n-2)) - 6

=> 2n + log (n^2 - 2n) - 6