# 2d coordinates closest to origin

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, performance

I am looking at the following interview question :

> Given 2d coordinates , find the k points which are closest to the
>   origin. Propose a data structure for storing the points and the method to get the k points. Also point out the complexity of the code.

The solution that I have figured out is to save the 2d points in an array. For the first k points, find the distance of each point from the origin and build a max heap. For the remaining points , calculate distance from the origin , say dist. If dist is greater than the topmost element of the heap, then change topmost element of heap to dist and run the `heapify()` procedure.

This would take `O(k)` to build the heap and `O((n-k)log k)` for `heapify()` procedure , thus the total complexity = `O(n log k)`.

Can anyone suggest a **better data structure** and/or method , with a possibly better efficiency too ?

EDIT

Would some other data structure be beneficial here ?

Comment: You can actually do this in time O(n) and space O(k), where k is the number of closest points that you want, by using a very clever trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202315/algorithm-to-find-100-closest-stars-to-the-origin

Comment: I'm wandering how can you design the data structure to return the points, that is return maybe set of pair<int, int>, but not array or distances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use order statistics for this one.
Note that we use a modified `SELECT` that uses distance from the origin as the comparison function.

- Store the elements in an array `A`, first element is `A[1]` and last is `A[n]`.
- Run `SELECT(A,1,n,k)` to find the `k`th closest element to the origin.
- Return the elements `A[1..k]`.

One of the benefits of `SELECT`that it partitions the input,
so that the smallest `k-1` elements are left to `A[k]`.

So storing the elements in an array is `O(n)`.
Running `SELECT` is `O(n)`.
Returning the requested elements is `O(1)`.

Comment: (1) `SELECT` takes O(n^2) time in worst case. (2) Step 3 above is not needed as I require all k points which are closest to origin but the algorithm would not need to be modified.

Comment: I noticed that you asked a question from CLRS. you can see there that there is a none randomized version of SELECT that runs in O(n) worst case. It uses median of medians.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is [partial sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting).

I think the best way is to put everything into an unsorted array and then do use a modified in-place quicksort which ignores partitions whose indices are entirely above or entirely below `k`, and use distance from origin as your comparison.

Pseudocode from the wikipedia article above:

```
function quickfindFirstK(list, left, right, k)
     if right > left
         select pivotIndex between left and right
         pivotNewIndex := partition(list, left, right, pivotIndex)
         if pivotNewIndex > left + k  // new condition
             quickfindFirstK(list, left, pivotNewIndex-1, k)
         if pivotNewIndex < left + k
             quickfindFirstK(list, pivotNewIndex+1, right, k+left-pivotNewIndex-1)
```

After execution, this will leave the smallest `k` items in the first `k` positions, but not in order.

Answer (score 1):

I write a simple version for you using so-called 'partial sorting'  http://tzutalin.blogspot.sg/2017/02/interview-type-questions-minqueue.html

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point[] points = new Point[7];
    points[0] = new Point(0, 0);
    points[1] = new Point(1, 7);
    points[2] = new Point(2, 2);
    points[3] = new Point(2, 2);
    points[4] = new Point(3, 2);
    points[5] = new Point(1, 4);
    points[6] = new Point(1, 1);
    int k = 3;
    qSelect(points, k - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        System.out.println("" + points[i].x + "," + points[i].y);
    }
    // Output will be
    //        0,0
    //        1,1
    //        2,2
}

// in-place qselect and zero-based
static void qSelect(Point[] points, int k) {
    int l = 0;
    int h = points.length - 1;
    while (l <= h) {
        int partionInd = partition(l, h, points);
        if (partionInd == k) {
            return;
        } else if (partionInd < k) {
            l = partionInd + 1;
        } else {
            h = partionInd - 1;
        }
    }
}

static int partition(int l, int h, Point[] points) {
    // Random can be better
    // int p = l + new Random.nextInt(h - l + 1);
    int p = l + (h - l) / 2;
    int ind = l;
    swap(p, h, points);
    Point comparePoint = points[h];
    for (int i = l; i < h; i++) {
        if (points[i].getDistFromCenter() < comparePoint.getDistFromCenter()) {
            swap(i, ind, points);
            ind++;
        }
    }
    swap(ind, h, points);
    return ind;
}

static void swap(int i, int j, Point[] points) {
    Point temp = points[i];
    points[i] = points[j];
    points[j] = temp;
}
```