# What's the equivalent 'nth_element' function in Java?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, stl, selection

I don't want get a sorted array, just nth element's value.   For example, given the array

```
 a = [20, 5, 1, -3]
```

I'd like to be able to query

```
nth_element(a,2) = 1
```

In C++, there is a function `std::nth_element` that can do this.  Is there an equivalent Java function?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a built in method? No, one does not exist in the standard library.

Comment: @Justin - he's asking for the nth element if the array is sorted, but without the overhead of needing to sort the array. C++ has an STL algorithm for the equivalent: http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/

Comment: Here is a question that describes some possible efficient algorithms (if you want something faster than sorting the array first).  They are not exactly trivial.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on

Comment: Title has "in java" question has "a java function", why do the tags have C++?

Answer (score 6):

The Java standard library does not contain an equivalent of the C++ `nth_element` algorithm.  The closest that you'll get would be to use `Collections.sort`.

Alternatively, you could try implementing your own version of this function.  You could implement `nth_element`by doing a standard sort and calling `Collections.sort`, though depending on your time requirements this may be too slow.  There are many specialized algorithms for performing this sort of reordering that are called *selection algorithms* and [the Wikipedia page on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) has several good examples.  Empirically, the fastest algorithm is called quickselect and is based on the quicksort algorithm; it runs in expected O(n) time but can degrade to O(n<sup>2</sup>) for pathologically bad inputs.  There is a famous (and notoriously complex) algorithm sometimes called the median-of-medians algorithm that runs in worst-case O(n), but has a high constant factor that prevents it from being used in practice.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Java implementation of nth_element:

```
class Nth_element
{ 
    static void nth_element_helper2(double[] arr, int beg, int end)
    {
        for(int i = beg + 1; i < end; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i; j > beg; j--)
            {
                if(arr[j - 1] < arr[j])
                    break;
                double t = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                arr[j - 1] = t;
            }
        }
    }

    static void nth_element_helper(double[] arr, int beg, int end, int index)
    {
        if(beg + 4 >= end)
        {
            nth_element_helper2(arr, beg, end);
            return;
        }
        int initial_beg = beg;
        int initial_end = end;

        // Pick a pivot (using the median of 3 technique)
        double pivA = arr[beg];
        double pivB = arr[(beg + end) / 2];
        double pivC = arr[end - 1];
        double pivot;
        if(pivA < pivB)
        {
            if(pivB < pivC)
                pivot = pivB;
            else if(pivA < pivC)
                pivot = pivC;
            else
                pivot = pivA;
        }
        else
        {
            if(pivA < pivC)
                pivot = pivA;
            else if(pivB < pivC)
                pivot = pivC;
            else
                pivot = pivB;
        }

        // Divide the values about the pivot
        while(true)
        {
            while(beg + 1 < end && arr[beg] < pivot)
                beg++;
            while(end > beg + 1 && arr[end - 1] > pivot)
                end--;
            if(beg + 1 >= end)
                break;

            // Swap values
            double t = arr[beg];
            arr[beg] = arr[end - 1];
            arr[end - 1] = t;

            beg++;
            end--;
        }
        if(arr[beg] < pivot)
            beg++;

        // Recurse
        if(beg == initial_beg || end == initial_end)
            throw new RuntimeException("No progress. Bad pivot");
        if(index < beg) // This is where we diverge from QuickSort. We only recurse on one of the two sides. This is what makes nth_element fast.
            nth_element_helper(arr, initial_beg, beg, index);
        else
            nth_element_helper(arr, beg, initial_end, index);
    }

    static double nth_element(double[] arr, int index)
    {
        nth_element_helper(arr, 0, arr.length, index);
        return arr[index];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] arr = { 9, 7, 1, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 8, 0, 10 };
        if(nth_element(arr, 5) == 5)
            System.out.println("seems to work");
        else
            System.out.println("broken");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java I think you have to implement it, something like this:

```
Integer nth_smallest_element(Integer[] originalArray, n) {
    if (n >= originalArray.length)
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid index");
    // Don't pass in your array, if you don't want it to be modified. Instead add them all later.
    List<Integer> copyList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    copyList.addAll(originalArray);
    Collections.sort(copyList);
    return copyList.get(n);
}
```

Comment: This misses the point though. `nth_smallest_element` could be done in O(n), but your solution is at least O(n lg n). You don't have to sort the entire thing.

Comment: The best algorithm I can think of to get nth_smallest_element includes n * lg n - n/2 * lg n/2 comparisons in the worst case (say, looking for the 100th smallest in 200 items). I'd really want to know if there is a better way of doing that in O(n). Sorting is a bit more expensive, but it is cleaner and easier.

Comment: They're called "Selection Algorithm's", Wikipedia has some info, as does [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on).

Comment: Thanks GMan for the lead. I knew 'quick sort', but didn't know about 'quick select'. I wouldn't personally use this algorithm if I had to implement it myself and spend half a day testing it ;-)

Comment: The question specifically references std::nth_element, which is the C++ STL implementation of O(n) selection algorithm.  Well, I guess it is not required to use that algorithm, but in practice that is obviously the chosen implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Quickselect algorithm is now implemented in AlgART library:
https://bitbucket.org/DanielAlievsky/algart/src/master/src/main/java/net/algart/arrays/ArraySelector.java
You can just use it via Maven, as described here:
http://algart.net/java/AlgART/

Answer (score 0):

There are the corresponding methods in class `java.lang.reflect.Array`<sup>**1**</sup>, see its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html)

Example:

```
var array = new int[] { 20, 5, 1, -3};
var value = java.lang.reflect.Array.getInt(array, 2);
```

---

**1** - not to confuse with `java.sql.Array`