# finding the middle value without sorting

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the kth largest element in an unsorted array of length n in O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on)

Is there any algorithm of finding the middle value of given list without performing the sorting operation.

for example if the list is maintained as stack and contains ( 1,2,5,3,4,6 ) then the middle value should be 4 
so my question is how to get this value without performing the sorting operation on the list.

is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you want to sort the list? *curious*

Comment: how do you compute the middle value ? As far as I can see, it could be 3 or 4 in your example.

Comment: Why is 4 the middle value? Is that an average of 3 and 4 rounded up?

Comment: Probably the OP just wants the median.  Most sorts are nlogn but there are near-linear algorithms. Not that they are necessarily faster, but they are interesting.

Comment: i did sorting so obtained 1 2 3 4 5 6 then mid=list[size()/2+1] and that is equal to 4

Comment: Without sorting it's not possible.Even if you will go for any algorithm it must do the sorting internally to find middle value.So it does not matter internally or external.Finally sorting is there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are well-known algorithms to find the kth largest element of a list.  See [How to find the kth largest element in an unsorted array of length n in O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on)

Here `k` is pre-computed as `length/2` of course, adjusted to the nearest integer if there are an even number of elements in your list.