# second largest number in an array at most n + log(n) -2 comparisons

Tags: algorithm, big-o, divide-and-conquer

When i see that problem i think i could use divide and conquer to solve 
[algorithm chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kTqj.png)

second her's my code
[program code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ljjm.png) sorry i can't write it here cause i wrote it in inline compiler and the file didn't saved

the code work well but when i calculate the n comparison it was bigger than  n + log(n) -2

my question(problem) is i can't solve the problem based on specific run time or specific comparison i solve the problem then calculate the comparison

i speak in general not just for that problem

how can i design(think about) an algorithm based on run time, is there steps to follow or what

Comment: Go through this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889679/find-second-largest-number-in-array-at-most-nlog%e2%82%82n%e2%88%922-comparisons

Answer (score 1):

Run an elimination tournament (`n - 1` comparisons). The second largest must be among those who lost to the champion, and there are `log n` of them. Find the largest of the candidates in `log(n) - 1` comparisons.

The hardest part is to design an efficient data structure to have the lists of the defeated opponents handy. This is highly non-trivial. For example, take a look at Alex Stepanov's [solution](https://github.com/rjernst/stepanov-components-course/tree/master/code/lecture9).

PS: I highly recommend the entire [course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHxtyCq_WDLXryyw91lahwdtpZsmo4BGD).