# Output the 10th highest number in an unsorted array

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the kth largest element in an unsorted array of length n in O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on)

How do I write an algorithm to output the **10th highest** number in an unsorted array of size **n** (in Java)?

Comment: Question has already been answered..

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on

please search once before asking... :-)

Comment: i have got nothing, just starting from the scratch.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm), which can finds the kth biggest/smallest number in an array in `O(n)`

It can also be done using a partial sort, or using a min-heap of a fixed size `k`, which will contain the `k`th highest numbers at each time, and iterate the array while maintaining this heap.

Note that the last solution [min-heap] is less efficient then selection algorithm in terms of big O notation, for the general problem of an arbitrary `k`.

Comment: Though, admittedly, if it's always the tenth-largest this might be massively overkilling the problem. :-)

Comment: yeah, so which particular algorithm of the selection algorithm should i use

Comment: @user: Whichever you like. You can also sort and just extract the highest 10 numbers, which would be `O(n * log n)` instead of `O(n)` for a hardcoded number of items.

Comment: @user1305400: [referring to arbitrary `k`]: It depends what you want, if you want a guaranteed `O(n)` worst case complexity - the median of medians solution is the way to do. If you want good performance on average case - I'd use [partition based selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Partition-based_general_selection_algorithm), and if you want easiest to program, and you already have heap implementation - the heap solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of 10 elements.  Keep the elements of your array sorted.

Passing through the original array once, compare the element with the smallest in your array of 10.  If it is larger, put it in.  Otherwise move on.

Comment: Note that maintaing this array will require `k` ops per each element you insert. I don't know if it will be better or worse then a heap for `k == 10` - but for larger `k` values - it will start becoming an issue.

Comment: Actually, it'll require an average of k/2 ops.

Comment: And for k=10 it is unlikely to be worth structuring the array as a heap.  Log 2 of 10 is between 3 and 4, but the cost of an operation is greater.

Comment: And you you typically will insert very few elements relative to n, since most of the time you're scanning past elements that are less than the min in the array of 10.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [Prune and Search](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/41235/Prune-and-search) algorithm if the array does not containt discrete elements (is contains for example doubles). If is contains discrete elements (integers) - use [Counting sort](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/40549/Counting-sort) and pick 10th element)