# Find the median of the sum of the arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, median

Two sorted arrays of length *n* are given and the question is to find, in O(*n*) time, the median of their sum array, which contains all the possible pairwise sums between every element of array A and every element of array B.

For instance: Let A[2,4,6] and B[1,3,5] be the two given arrays.
The sum array is `[2+1,2+3,2+5,4+1,4+3,4+5,6+1,6+3,6+5]`. Find the median of this array in O(*n*).

Solving the question in O(*n^2*) is pretty straight-forward but is there any O(*n*) solution to this problem?

Note: This is an interview question asked to one of my friends and the interviewer was quite sure that it can be solved in O(*n*) time.

Comment: Are arrays sorted in the beginning?

Comment: Well, it can be done in `O(n + n log n)`

Comment: Do you know if the median of the sum is the sum of the medians ?

Comment: There is a description on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the median of an unsorted array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662013/finding-the-median-of-an-unsorted-array)

Comment: Hey, OP states the sum of arrays more like Cartesian product, the result array contains `N*N` elements. Be aware.

Comment: @Mikhail The arrays are sorted to begin with. Missed this info in the question. Thanks

Comment: @Jon There are O(n*n) elements in the Cartesian product sum thingy, in which case generating it and just finding the median of it will not be O(n).

Comment: Ugh. It's definitely possible (Mirzaian–Arjomandi 1985), but expecting the O(n) algorithm in an interview is lunacy.

Comment: We can generate the sum array in O(n) and use quickselect to get the median of an unsorted array in O(n). Figured with help of google

Comment: @user814628 that's O(n^2) not O(n)

Comment: @aaronman can you explain which part?

Comment: @user814628 both because the size of the new list is O(n^2)

Comment: Here is a link to Mirzaian–Arjomandi 1985, as mentioned by David: http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~andy/pubs/X+Y.pdf

Comment: @David Eisenstat: expecting the correct algorithm is lunacy.. but maybe they weren't looking for that. You would be shocked how many candidates can come up with wrong answers and be convinced that they work without testing (and proving) them.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath then what are you supposed to do in an interview like that

Comment: @H2CO3 `O(n + nlogn)` is the same as `O(nlogn)`

Comment: Starting with your sorted arrays you could compose the final array (at least the first n/2 + 1 elements) in such a way that it will be already sorted.

Comment: Knowing that one corner contains the minimum value, and the opposite corner contains the maximum value, my intuition says to start with pointers in the two remaining corners -- from those positions you can either get a lower or higher value by moving horizontally or vertically as required.  Walk these two pointers together until they meet?  Unfortunately I haven't the time to confirm that this is on the right track.  I guess I'll just read others answers, now.  Handwavey "proof" centres around knowledge of state of quadrants and extra knowledge from other pointer blah blah blah...

Comment: If I was out of work with even a nickle in the bank that is not a company I would want to work for.  They should ask a question based on  an actual current problem.

Comment: Agreed -- it's a dumb question to ask in a job interview.  Asking what thought process you'd use to attack it might be reasonable, but that requires a pretty insightful interviewer.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I agree, but it's cruel and unusual to toss out a running time without a disclaimer that it was publishable stuff thirty years ago. That goes double if, as could be the case, it's slower for non-galactic n than a simple O(n log n)-time algorithm.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Never mind that asking questions this hard is generally bad practice in interviews.  "Are you familiar with this Stupid Theory Trick?" isn't something any programmer will ever have to care about.  Unless he has a hard problem and needs to feel confident that there's no point looking in the literature.

Comment: Funny part is interviewer was quite adamant on finding an O(n) solution and continued on this question for more than 45 minutes.

Comment: While I don't necessarily credit any interviewer with insight matching the toughness of the question they ask, it's worth noting that a question where the candidate stands to answer successfully puts an upper limit on the discussion that can be had in the process.  A string of easy questions to be knocked down one at a time really _would_ be a test of experience with clever tricks.  And an actual coding test would mean admitting that programming work tends to be a lot more mundane than anybody wants to admit.

Answer (score 14):

The correct O(n) solution is quite complicated, and takes a significant amount of text, code and skill to explain and prove. More precisely, it takes 3 pages to do so convincingly, as can be seen in details here http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~andy/pubs/X+Y.pdf (found by `simonzack` in the comments).

It is basically a clever divide-and-conquer algorithm that, among other things, takes advantage of the fact that in a sorted n-by-n matrix, one can find in `O(n)` the amount of elements that are smaller/greater than a given number `k`. It recursively breaks down the matrix into smaller submatrixes (*by taking only the odd rows and columns, resulting in a submatrix that has `n/2` colums and `n/2` rows*) which combined with the step above, results in a complexity of `O(n) + O(n/2) + O(n/4)... = O(2*n) = O(n)`. It is crazy!

I can't explain it better than the paper, **which is why I'll explain a simpler, `O(n logn)` solution instead :)**.

---

## O(n * logn) solution:

**It's an interview!** You can't get that `O(n)` solution in time. So hey, why not provide a solution that, although not optimal, shows you can do better than the other obvious `O(n²)` candidates?

I'll make use of the `O(n)` algorithm mentioned above, to find the amount of numbers that are smaller/greater than a given number `k` in a sorted `n-by-n` matrix. Keep in mind that we don't need an actual matrix! The Cartesian sum of two arrays of size `n`, as described by the OP, results in a sorted `n-by-n` matrix, which we can simulate by considering the elements of the array as follows:

```
a[3] = {1, 5, 9};
b[3] = {4, 6, 8};
//a + b:
{1+4, 1+6, 1+8,
 5+4, 5+6, 5+8,
 9+4, 9+6, 9+8}
```

Thus each row contains non-decreasing numbers, and so does each column. Now, pretend you're given a number `k`. We want to find in `O(n)` how many of the numbers in this matrix are smaller than `k`, and how many are greater. Clearly, if both values are less than `(n²+1)/2`, that means `k` is our median!

The algorithm is pretty simple:

```
int smaller_than_k(int k){
    int x = 0, j = n-1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        while(j >= 0 && k <= a[i]+b[j]){
            --j;
        }
        x += j+1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

This basically counts how many elements fit the condition at each row. Since the rows and columns are already sorted as seen above, this will provide the correct result. And as both `i` and `j` iterate at most `n` times each, the algorithm is `O(n)` [*Note that `j` does not get reset within the `for` loop*]. The `greater_than_k` algorithm is similar.

Now, how do we choose `k`? That is the `logn` part. **Binary Search!** As has been mentioned in other answers/comments, the median must be a value contained within this array:

`candidates[n] = {a[0]+b[n-1], a[1]+b[n-2],... a[n-1]+b[0]};`.

Simply sort this array [also `O(n*logn)`], and run the binary search on it. Since the array is now in non-decreasing order, it is straight-forward to notice that the amount of numbers smaller than each `candidate[i]` is also a non-decreasing value (monotonic function), which makes it suitable for the binary search. The largest number `k = candidate[i]` whose result `smaller_than_k(k)` returns smaller than `(n²+1)/2` is the answer, and is obtained in `log(n)` iterations:

```
int b_search(){
    int lo = 0, hi = n, mid, n2 = (n²+1)/2;
    while(hi-lo > 1){
        mid = (hi+lo)/2;
        if(smaller_than_k(candidate[mid]) < n2)
            lo = mid;
        else
            hi = mid;
    }
    return candidate[lo]; // the median
}
```

Comment: "And as both i and j iterate at most n times each, the algorithm is O(n)" => Shouldn't it be O(n^2)?

Comment: @KhanhNguyen `j` does not depend on `i`. It starts at `n-1` and gets subtracted at most `n` times in total (it does not get reset to `n-1`). So there are at most `2*n` iterations combined.

Comment: But there's another problem: if I am right, after getting the candidates sorted, you run `smaller_than_k(k)` on *each* candidate, until you find the one. Wouldn't that make it `O(n^2)` in the worst case?

Comment: @KhanhNguyen I do not run on *each* candidate, that is exactly where Binary Search kicks in. After sorting the array, I need only run `smaller_than_k()` on `log(n)` elements of it to obtain the one which represents the median, as described in the last step.

Comment: Could you explain in detail why the answer is amongst `candidates`? Other answers gives only an idea, but I cannot come out with a thorough proof.

Comment: The median doesn't necessarily lie on the diagonal of the matrix (the given `candidates` matrix), as @Mikhail wonders. Consider `[1,2,3,4]` and `[10,20,30,40]`. `candidates` is `[14,23,32,41]` but the median is the average of 24 and 31.

Comment: can you elaborate on candidate ? I don't think it is correct .

Comment: if the number of elements in the array is even, then of course the median is never in any of the sums - but that can be done with an extra check before returning `candidate[lo]`, as basically that means both `[lo]` and `[lo+1]` will fail the greater/smaller checks respectively, and in such case, return `(candidate[lo]+candidate[lo+1])/2`. You don't even need to do the checks as you know this beforehand when `n` is even.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the arrays are `A = {A[1] ... A[n]}`, and `B = {B[1] ... B[n]}`, and the pairwise sum array is `C = {A[i] + B[j], where 1 <= i <= n, 1 <= j <= n}` which has `n^2` elements and we need to find its median.

Median of `C` must be an element of the array `D = {A[1] + B[n], A[2] + B[n - 1], ... A[n] + B[1]}`: if you fix `A[i]`, and consider all the sums `A[i] + B[j]`, you would see that the *only* `A[i] + B[j = n + 1 - i]` (which is one of `D`) *could be* the median. That is, it may not be the median, but if it is not, then all other `A[i] + B[j]` are also not median.

This can be proved by considering all `B[j]` and count the *number of values* that are **lower** and *number of values* that are **greater** than `A[i] + B[j]` (we can do this quite accurately because the two arrays are sorted -- the calculation is a bit messy thought). You'd see that for `A[i] + B[n + 1 - j]` these two counts are most "balanced".

The problem then reduces to finding median of `D`, which has only `n` elements. An algorithm such as [Hoare's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) will work.

**UPDATE**: this answer is wrong. The real conclusion here is that the **median** is one of `D`'s element, but then *`D`'s median* is the not the same as `C`'s median.

Comment: this is what aaronman said, isn't it?  i thought there was a counter-example?

Comment: if you can't read deleted posts, consider [0 1 1 1 2] and [0 0 0 1 2].  if i've understood you correctly, your "diagonal" is [2 2 1 1 2] and the median of that is 2.  but the correct result is 1.

Comment: Somone found the solution in the paper, but it would be nice if it could be delivered in code in c++ or java, or at least explained in less mathematical terms than in the paper

Comment: @andrewcooke there is the two answers not deleted right now are oversimplifying the problem, the solution is known and it is a pretty complex algo if you read the paper

Comment: @aaronman when i skimmed the paper it seemed much more general than the question here.  i haven't worked out whether the median is a simpler special case and i didn't see it mentioned in the paper (but i really did only only skim it).  what i am posting here helps other people understand that they are wrong.  a counter example is much more convincing than "it's hard and you're dumb".

Comment: @andrewcooke The paper is a solution for finding the nth largest element out of an ordered matrix or one that would be constructed from summing the cross product of two vectors X+Y. Median is just the nth largest element where n = size/2. So, the paper is a solution for this problem.

Comment: @Patashu  i am not saying the paper doesn't solve the problem.  when i said "i haven't worked out whether the median is a simpler special case" what i meant is, perhaps median is a special case that has a simpler solution than the general approach given in the paper.  i don't know, and i didn't give it much thought.  but i am not quetsioning that the paper has a solution.

Comment: @aaronman You (or I) *don't* have to delete your answer when it is wrong. There is no rules SO saying that you can't post wrong answer, as long as you invest enought time and effort into it. Just downvote it, leave a note for later viewers. All we are trying to do is contribute a good answer. My answer was wrong, but it is an idea. By leaving it here, future viewers won't make the same mistake (and hopefully derive an answer by improving it). And, if you haven't deleted your post, I wouldn't have wasted my time on trying the same idea!

Comment: @andrewcooke a counter example is good, but it's even better if you can point out which step is wrong. No offense though, good job with the counter example :)

Comment: @KhanhNguyen - after some karma level you can see deleted posts.  it's easy to forget that not everyone can (sorry).  the wrong bit is in the counting, i would guess.  the bit you didn't explain...

Comment: I don't think I asked you to delete it at any point, but I deleted mine because I felt that there was no reason to keep it and it was on the wrong track

Comment: @andrewcooke Maybe, but I saw a(nother) hole. I added an update, actually I should have seen it from begining, my answer never gave a fractional answer (ie average of two values), which must happen when both arrays have odd number of elements.

Comment: If you know the answer is wrong, you should probably delete it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the only reason he isn't is because it has 2 up-votes and only 2 down-votes(net gain)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work?:

You can compute the rank of a number in linear time as long as `A` and `B` are sorted.  The technique you use for computing the rank can also be used to find all things in `A+B` that are between some lower bound and some upper bound in time linear the size of the output plus `|A|+|B|`.

Randomly sample `n` things from `A+B`.  Take the median, say `foo`.  Compute the rank of `foo`.  With constant probability, `foo`'s rank is within `n` of the median's rank.  Keep doing this (an expected constant number of times) until you have lower and upper bounds on the median that are within `2n` of each other.  (This whole process takes expected linear time, but it's obviously slow.)

All you have to do now is enumerate everything between the bounds and do a linear-time selection on a linear-sized list.

(Unrelatedly, I wouldn't excuse the interviewer for asking such an obviously crappy interview question.  Stuff like this in no way indicates your ability to code.)

**EDIT**:  You can compute the rank of a number `x` by doing something like this:

```
Set i = j = 0.
While j < |B| and A[i] + B[j] <= x, j++.
While i < |A| {
  While A[i] + B[j] > x and j >= 0, j--.
  If j < 0, break.
  rank += j+1.
  i++.
}
```

**FURTHER EDIT**:  Actually, the above trick only narrows down the candidate space to about n log(n) members of `A+B`.  Then you have a general selection problem within a universe of size n log(n); you can do basically the same trick one more time and find a range of size proportional to sqrt(n) log(n) where you do selection.

Here's why:  If you sample k things from an n-set and take the median, then the sample median's order is between the (1/2 - sqrt(log(n) / k))th and the (1/2 + sqrt(log(n) / k))th elements with at least constant probability.  When n = |A+B|, we'll want to take k = sqrt(n) and we get a range of about sqrt(n log n) elements --- that's about |A| log |A|.  But then you do it again and you get a range on the order of sqrt(n) polylog(n).

Comment: So the rank takes higher than linear (nested for loop) solution is not linear

Comment: Anything that says "randomly" usually has worst case complexity infinity.

Comment: No, the rank computation is obviously linear.  And this is called a "Las Vegas" algorithm; it always returns the correct answer and its expected runtime is nice.

Comment: `All you have to do now is enumerate everything between the bounds and do a linear-time selection on a linear-sized list.`
How exactly do you plan on computing this list? Keep in mind the numbers do not need to be small, your list of 2n numbers could have a lower bound of 10^7 and higher bound of 10^9 and you need to figure out what are those 2n numbers in it. Other than that, your solution is kind of similar to mine, except I use a binary search instead of a random algorithm.

Comment: @Arthur: You compute that list just like you compute the ranks.  Find lower and upper bounds on `j` for each `i` so that everything within the range lies between the bounds.  Then you can enumerate those few elements of `A+B` that matter.  Random sampling tricks like this are usually the key to defeating binary search.  (As a bonus, it often runs faster in practice.  I wasn't convinced of its practical use either until I saw someone actually use a trick like this.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a selection algorithm to find the median of an unsorted list in O(n). Look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm