# Finding median of an unsorted array in linear time?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance, arraylist

After careful research and thought, I decided to post this question which is a "sequel" to my previous question asked earlier today.

I made an algorithm that finds the median of an ArrayList and bascially all I do is make a temporary ArrayList, then using Collections.sort() on that ArrayList, I can easily get the median. The problem with that is it takes too long for larger files and I am trying(without luck) to find an implementation of an algorithm to get the median of an unsorted Array(or ArrayList).

From what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662013/finding-the-median-of-an-unsorted-array), the Median of Medians algorithm is used followed by QuickSelect but I cannot find an actual implementation that is easy enough to understand.

Here's a snippet of my code that finds the median of an ArrayList of size `filterSize`:

```
while(elements.size()-counter >= filterSize){
            for(int i = 0; i<filterSize; i++){
                tempElements.add(this.elements.get(i+counter));
                if(i==filterSize){
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            Collections.sort(tempElements); //Sort tempElements to find median
            outputElements.add(tempElements.get((filterSize-1)/2)); //Add median to an output ArrayList after calculating median index
            
            counter++;
            tempElements.clear(); //Removes all elements from the tempElements and start again
        }
```

Basically I'm trying to avoid the whole use of `Collections.sort()` and `tempElements.clear()` in the code, thus the reason to find a better algorithm for finding the median in linear time.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as non-intuitive algorithms go, *Median of Medians* is pretty high on the ladder. I doubt that there would be an implementation of this algorithm that is easy to understand, because the algorithm itself is not particularly easy to understand.

Comment: I imagine you could use quicksort, and always follow the half that covers the element at index size/2, and ignore the other half.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Exactly. It's really hard to get it. And I'm pretty new to Data Structures and Algorithms as well. But do you think it's worth to replace my current algorithm with Median of Medians(if at all possible) ?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb that is exactly the quickselect algorithm.

Comment: Why not try it with only switching from sorting to using quick select first?  Then, if that's still not fast enough, start messing around with median of medians.

Answer (score 4):

I think the basic [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm (code below from this link) is quite easy to understand: you pick a pivot, apply Quicksort's partition function and then see where that pivot ends up, recursing accordingly to only one of the halves.

```
 function partition(list, left, right, pivotIndex)
     pivotValue := list[pivotIndex]
     swap list[pivotIndex] and list[right]  // Move pivot to end
     storeIndex := left
     for i from left to right-1
         if list[i] < pivotValue
             swap list[storeIndex] and list[i]
             increment storeIndex
     swap list[right] and list[storeIndex]  // Move pivot to its final place
     return storeIndex

  // Returns the n-th smallest element of list within left..right inclusive
  // (i.e. left <= n <= right).
  // The size of the list is not changing with each recursion.
  // Thus, n does not need to be updated with each round.
  function select(list, left, right, n)
     if left = right        // If the list contains only one element,
         return list[left]  // return that element
     pivotIndex  := ...     // select a pivotIndex between left and right,
                            // e.g., left + floor(rand() * (right - left + 1))
     pivotIndex  := partition(list, left, right, pivotIndex)
     // The pivot is in its final sorted position
     if n = pivotIndex
         return list[n]
     else if n < pivotIndex
         return select(list, left, pivotIndex - 1, n)
     else
         return select(list, pivotIndex + 1, right, n)
```

Compared to median of medians, this can degenerate to `O(n^2)`, but you can significantly reduce the chances of that happening by choosing the pivot randomly, like described in the comments.

If you're not happy with an implementation of median of medians that you don't fully understand, I suggest you go for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to another answer, "Quickselect" for finding the median has very tight running time guarantees if you randomly choose each pivot, namely "almost certain" linear time, meaning that the probability of getting a running time greater than cn goes to 0 very quickly as the constant c grows, as n becomes large. So unless you are worried about odds even less likely than winning the lottery, for all intents and purposes there is a constant c such that you will never see a running time greater than cn, regardless of n.