# Is there a definitive algorithm to find the median of an array of unsorted integers in O(n) time and is deterministic

Tags: sorting, time-complexity

I have found some questions similar to this on the site but they do not give a deterministic solution , like the [median of median](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662013/finding-the-median-of-an-unsorted-array) approach which is only gives an approximate albeit low error value of the median.

Thus I am looking for a 'black box' algorithm that is complete in itself and is deterministic as an answer.

Comment: No, if you need the correct answer, you can't do it in linear time, if you need linear time an approximation is the best you can get.

Comment: There is [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect), which is Θ(n) on average, but Θ(n²) in the worst-case.