# How to get sum of all values a variable holds after for loop?

Tags: c++, arrays

i am currently having problem getting sum of all values a variable holds, here is my code i want to print the sum of max variable as it outputs 3 values at the end but i want to print the sum of those 3  values.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int a[10], max, prior_max = numeric_limits<int>::max();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
        cin>>a[i];

    }
  for( int j = 0; j<3; j++){
    max = numeric_limits<int>::min();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
        if(a[i]>max && a[i]<prior_max){
            max=a[i];
        }
    }
    cout << max << endl;
    prior_max = max;

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is an elegant solution of this problem using priority queue built on heap data structure.

Comment: You are not honestly asking, how to calculate the sum of 3 instances of a variable, are you?

Comment: This issue is a parallel issue posted in this question by this member. The initial code of this question is the code that I provided as the answer for a prior part of the initial question -- How to get largest value after leaving one array value?. Then this member asked the follow on question as a comment to my answer, where the member asked about how to compute the total. As I did not answer withing an hour of his asking the follow on question, it was posted here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534940/how-to-get-largest-value-after-leaving-one-array-value

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int a[10], max, prior_max = numeric_limits<int>::max();
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    long int sum = 0;   // <------------------------------------

    for (int j = 0; j<3; j++) 
    {
        max = numeric_limits<int>::min();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            if (a[i] > max && a[i] < prior_max) 
            {
                max = a[i];
            }
        }
        cout << "max = " << max << endl;
        prior_max = max;
        sum += max;  //  <----------------------------------------
    }       
    cout << "sum = " << sum << endl;   //    <--------------------------------
}
```

Comment: it doesn't prints the sum, why?

Comment: Aren't you forgetting the most important thing: `sum+=max`? ;)

Comment: The best thing to do is to use a debugger. Step through the program and watch as the values change. You will soon sport the problem. Btw, Mike is correct, I made a typo. As it stands `sum == max;` does nothing (although sum should still be printed as 0). It should be `sum += max;` I will update the answer. BUt do learn to use the debugger. It is your best friend

Comment: Seriously? Now sum will be `3*numeric_limits<int>::min();`

Comment: Then I guess that I didn't understand the question. If you do, please help him. Or maybe he will learn to use the debugger. I'm off to bed now ... yaaaaaaaaaawnz. Nite nite :-)

Comment: Done - you just put the summation into the wrong line