# Working of Iterator in Java

Tags: java, software-design

I was implementing a code to return the nth Largest Number in an array,
Following is the code I implemented;

```
public int getNthLargestNum(int [] givenArr, int n){

    int nTotal=0;
    int nNthNum = -1;

    // Remove Duplicates
    Set<Integer> o_hs = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    for(int insert=0; insert<givenArr.length; insert++)
    {o_hs.add(givenArr[insert]);}

    Iterator it  = o_hs.iterator();
    int count=0;

    while(it.hasNext()){
        if(count == n){

        // IF I MOVE THE LINE HERE
        // nNthNum = (Integer)it.next();

            break;
        }
        nNthNum = (Integer)it.next();
        count++; 
    }

return nNthNum;    
}
```

If I input the array givenArr[4,14,4,5,6,8,9] and n=2 the output is 5 for the above program but if I move the line nNthNum = (Integer)it.next(); inside the if loop it outputs 4.

So I was curious to know to iterate through the loop we should always implement it.next()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `HashSet` is inherently unordered, so getting the N-th item from the set is meaningless.  You have no idea what value you get.  The algorithm is inherently arbitrary.  Instead iterate the sorted array to get the N-th largest value, or use a `TreeSet` which is *not* unordered.

Since you don't actually need the entire data in the sorted set you can remove items from the set as you go.  Technically, since the set only ever has a maximum of 5 items if you do that each operation is O(1), making the whole algorithm O(n).

```
public int getNthLargestNum(int[] data, int n){
    TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    foreach(int number : data)
    {
        set.add(number);
        if(set.size() > 5)
            set.pollFirst();
    }

    return set.first();
}
```

Comment: I was planning to use Set to reomove the duplicates. But TreeSet would take a perfomrance hit if the data is huge right? Is there any other way to remove duplicates. I understand I can use HashMaps and store the count as value, is there any other alternative than HashMap too?

Comment: `TreeSet` wouldn't incur any greater performance hit than you'd already get from `Arrays.sort`.

Comment: @JNL Calling `Sort` on your data will already have an equal performance impact to using a `SortedSet`.  Adding n items to a `SortedSet` is O(n*log(n)), sorting n items is O(n*log(n)).  By adding the items to a `SortedSet` you won't *need* to do the array sort.  Also, focus on getting working data first, then optimize as needed.  There's no sense using an algorithm that's way faster when it produces the wrong result.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the same Servy. I tried to break the earlier implementation with HashSet and including negative numbers and it did not work as intented. I edidted it to use TreeSet. I was wonderring if we can we do in O(n) time?

Comment: @JNL Yous should include that in the question then, it's simple enough to do.

Comment: @Servy  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on                This is the link for the same. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you don't do `it.next()`, next element in collection will not be fetched.

`it.hasNext()` call will not advance pointer to next element in collection.