# Find a element "k" such that there are "k" greater elements than this element in the unsorted array

Tags: arrays

Accolite Interview:

Input: Array of integers (no range given) , unsorted , size n

Output: Find a element "k" in the array, such that there are exactly "k" elements in the array which are greater than this element.

For example if the array is :

1.
[4,3,6,9,10,22]
Output here is 4

2.
[4,3,6,9,10]
output: No such number found

This question can be done very easily by sorting in O(n log n) Time , but i was asked to do it in O(n) time (and if O(logn) possible).

Comment: good luck with your home work, tell us if you got a real programmatic problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the kth largest element in an unsorted array of length n in O(n)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on)

Comment: You can't do it in O(log(n)) time. If the array is unsorted, you will have to look at every element once, which is O(n).

Comment: @Blender - I Read the link you suggested , but i guess that applies to questions in which you are provided with the value of "k". Here value of "k" is not provided, we have to find the value of "k"

Comment: yes O(logn) is not possible :)

Comment: is there any possibilities of duplicate numbers?

Comment: @stinePike I m not sure about that. Lets assume we can have duplicates. :) . If there's a solution without duplicates then please share :)

Comment: It's a trivial change in the algorithm for order statistics, as Blender said. Hint: in the original algorithm, you check of the current pivot is at the kth position; if not, you recurse on the side of the pivot that contains the index k; instead, try checking if the pivot satisfies your new condition (`k=n - pivot value`), and otherwise which side can contain the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Someone helped , here's the solution**

Point to note : **"K" cannot be greater than size of the array.** 
    We will have a count array of size equal to given array.

```
assuming indexes start from 1 
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
  if(a[i]<=n)
    count[a[i]-1]++;
  else
    count[n]++;
}



boolean flag=false;
 for(i=n-1;i>=1;i--)
 {
    if(count[i]==i)
    {
      flag=true;
      System.out.println("k: "+i);

    }
 }

 if(flag==false)
      System.out.println("No such number found);

}
```

Comment: Where is `k` in this algorithm? What are the bounds of your arrays? Also please refer to the source.

Comment: Output printed is the "k". Value of "k" is not given before hand, we have to find it.

Input array is a[1..n]

Comment: There is no way this works as written.  Ignoring the obvious problem of negative integers in the array, here's a  counter example: [ 2, 5, 6 ].  Your count[0..3] array will look like [ 0, 1, 0, 2 ], and you won't output the correct answer '2'.  You're on the right track though.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] count = new int[ n + 2 ];
for ( int k = 0; k < n; ++k )
    ++count[ Math.min( n + 1, Math.max( 0, a[ k ] + 1 ) ) ];
int k = n, c = count[ n + 1 ];
for ( ; k > 0 && ( 0 == count[ k ] || k != c ); c += count[ k-- ] );
System.out.println( 0 == k ? "not found" : "found: " + k );
```