# Big-O notation searching algorithm ?

Tags: java, big-o

I want to implement at least two different solutions to find N-th largest element with O(N*log(N)) average time complexity in Big-O notation, where N is the number of elements in the list ?

which searching algorithm should i use in my program in java to find to n-th largest element with regards to O(N*log(N)) ?

Comment: you would use a quicksort, mergesort or heapsort. Please have a look at this: http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem you are facing can be solve in linear time using the partitioning that is part of the `quick sort` algorithm(Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/251781/812912)). If you really need and `O(N*log(N))` algorithm than most efficient sorting algorithms will do - for instance quick sort, merge sort, heap sort.

Comment: perfect thank you .... i do have the implementation of quick sort, merge sort, heap sort by myself. However i was hoping to understand if they are predefined in java ?

Comment: Java's built-in sort uses `introsort` I believe. This is a mixture of several different sorting algorithms but it has a complexity of `O(N * log (N))`