# Searching algorithm with complexity O(log n), UNSORTED list/array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, complexity-theory

I had this exercice in an exam which stated:

> Find an algorithm which can search for the highest number in an
>   unsorted list and have a Big-Oh complexity of O(log(N)).

The only searching algorithm with a log n complexity that I have found is the binary search algorithm but that one requires my list/array to be sorted.

Is there such an algorithm?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a trick question. It has not been stated that the list has *N* elements. So, you can use a change of variable, and replace *N* with *2<sup>K</sup>*. Now, solve the problem with a linear algorithm on a list with *K* elements.

If we assume there are *N* elements in the list, a possible solution would be to use *N* parallel computing elements [ *CE<sub>0</sub> .. CE<sub>N</sub>* ]. In the base case of the algorithm, we let each computing element *CE<sub>i</sub>* in [ *CE<sub>N/2</sub> .. CE<sub>N</sub>* ] compare list values *x<sub>2i-N</sub>* and *x<sub>2i-N+1</sub>*. Each computing element reports the larger of their two assigned values to *CE<sub>i/2</sub>*. The iterative steps of the algorithm is that each computing element *CE<sub>k</sub>* that receives two reported values reports the largest to *CE<sub>k/2</sub>*. This iterative logic continues until *CE<sub>0</sub>* processes a report from itself. Instead of reporting to itself again, it outputs the result.

If parallel computation is ruled out, then there is no solution to the problem.

Comment: Don't understand the downvote.  This is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: Note that the parallel algorithm allows us to get to O(log n) time complexity, but the computational complexity is still O(n).

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such algorithms. In a unsorted list, find a highest number require to browse through all elements.

So, no algorithm better than O(n) exists!

Answer (score 2):

The best one can do is O(n) time in an unsorted array.

But instead of simply looking through the whole list you can apply a partition() routine (from the quicksort algorithm) and instead of recursing on the lower half of the partition you can recurse on the upper half and keep partitioning until the largest element is found. This takes O(n) time.

Check out for detailed explanation:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

[How to find the kth largest element in an unsorted array of length n in O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on)

Hope it helped! :)

Comment: As per the question O(n) is not good enough. A normal linear search would take O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

Ik this is very old, but if I had this question, I would have used the fact that it did not specify that the list is *N* elements long, meaning it’s valid to make the assumption that the list has 1 element, then a simple line of code like this should work giving you O(1) time complexity,

```
Answer= list[0]
```