# Finding k-th biggest element in set

Tags: c++

I'm using set in C++

```
set<int> Set;
```

And I would like to k-thest biggest element. How to do it? 
Plese give me hand,

Comment: You'll have more luck on SO if you provide code and show that you've done at least a little bit of your own research.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on

Comment: Please provide some attempt at finding the solution.  It doesn't need to be correct, but we need you to show some effort to help us answer where you need help.

Comment: This is not a duplicate--finding the largest element is different from finding the Kth element.

Answer (score 7):

It's impossible to do it in O(log n) time with std::set, but you can do it using `tree` from extended STL. Here is how to use it:

```
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
using namespace __gnu_pbds;
tree<int, null_type, less<int>, rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update> s;
s.insert(x);
s.erase(x);
s.count(x);
s.find_by_order(k);
// k-th biggest element in set
s.order_of_key(x);
// how many elements in set are less than x
```

Answer (score 2):

Elements in a set are stored in sorted order, so `Set.rbegin()` yields an iterator to the largest element in the set.

`std::next` will advance an iterator by a specified number of places, and return an iterator to that position.

You can combine these to get an iterator to the largest item, then advance it K elements back from there to get an iterator to the K<sup>th</sup> largest element, then dereference that to get the element itself.