# Find the nth largest element in an unsorted read only data struture with no extra space

Tags: algorithm, search

I need to find the nth largest element in a range, which is not random access range, with O(1) extra space. The heap method takes too much space. I found a solution [How to find the Kth smallest integer in an unsorted read only array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728297/how-to-find-the-kth-smallest-integer-in-an-unsorted-read-only-array) but it does not work for doubles. So is there a similar solution for doubles.

Comment: Why do you say that "it does not work for doubles" ???

Comment: For floating point numbers, i am not sure about terminating condition. And also if numbers are in a small range then extra time will be needed.

Comment: Extra time ? No.

Answer (score 1):

The key part is O(1) and possibly duplicate items. One possibility is:

Find the largest element smaller than the current maximum.
Find the number of elements equal to this.
Decrease until done.

Or in C-code something like:

```
double findKthLargest(double arr[], int nElements, int k) {
   double currentMax, nextMax;
   int currentK=0, nDuplicates;
   for(;;) {
     nDuplicates=0;
     for(int j=0;j<nElements;++j) {
        if (currentK==0 || arr[j]<currentMax) {
           // Possible max
           if (j==0 || arr[j]>nextMax) nextMax=arr[j];
        }
     }
     for(int j=0;j<nElements;++j) if (arr[j]==nextMax) nDuplicates++;
     if (currentK+nDuplicates>=k) return nextMax;
     currentMax=nextMax;
     currentK=currentK+nDuplicates;
}
```

Another is to order the duplicates by keeping track of their index.

Comment: Is there a faster solution. O(nk) is going to be too small

Answer (score 0):

If time does not matter:

Iterate the List n times and in each pass look for the largest element smaller than the one you found in the last pass.

If you want/need to handle duplicates you need a counter how often the 
all formerly searched largest elements occurred (all together = only one counter needed).

---

What size is your n that keeping a heap of n elements is not feasible option?

Comment: @PopescuDavidIoan: why not ?

Comment: Because you look for something smaller than a value, not an element. i think this approach would give you the n-th largest value, not element.

Comment: Example : [2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3], and n = 2. So we should iterate 2 times, the first iteration gives the value 3, and the second will give the value 2 ("look for the largest element smaller than the one you found in the last pass.")     But the correct answer is 3, for that is the 2nd largest element. 2 is the 2nd largest value

Comment: @Popescu David Ioan: As described in my updated answer you can easily extend the idea to handle duplicates too.

Comment: The size is about 10 million. So heap is noy feasible.

Comment: @Thambi: Depending on your datatype 10million entries need about 40megaBytes (if you implement it is an array).  That should be no problem.