# Overall complexity of finding Kth Largest element in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, heap, time-complexity, heapsort

I was solving this `leetcode` problem [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-largest-element-in-an-array/), and found an amazing solution using `heapq` module, the the running time of this function is very less. This is below program:

```
from itertools import islice
import heapq

def nlargest(n, iterable):
    """Find the n largest elements in a dataset.

    Equivalent to:  sorted(iterable, reverse=True)[:n]
    """
    if n < 0:
        return []
    it = iter(iterable)
    result = list(islice(it, n))
    if not result:
        return result
    heapq.heapify(result)
    _heappushpop = heapq.heappushpop
    for elem in it:
        _heappushpop(result, elem)
    result.sort(reverse=True)
    return result

print nlargest(5, [10, 122, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 10, 12, 23, 18, 17, 15, 100, 101])
```

This algorithm is really clever and you can also do the visualize here [LINK](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=from+itertools+import+islice%0Aimport+heapq%0A%0Adef+nlargest(n,+iterable%29%3A%0A++++%22%22%22Find+the+n+largest+elements+in+a+dataset.%0A%0A++++Equivalent+to%3A++sorted(iterable,+reverse%3DTrue%29%5B%3An%5D%0A++++%22%22%22%0A++++if+n+%3C+0%3A%0A++++++++return+%5B%5D%0A++++it+%3D+iter(iterable%29%0A++++result+%3D+list(islice(it,+n%29%29%0A++++if+not+result%3A%0A++++++++return+result%0A++++heapq.heapify(result%29%0A++++_heappushpop+%3D+heapq.heappushpop%0A++++for+elem+in+it%3A%0A++++++++_heappushpop(result,+elem%29%0A++++result.sort(reverse%3DTrue%29%0A++++return+result%0A%0Aprint+nlargest(5,+%5B10,+122,+2,+3,+3,+4,+5,+5,+10,+12,+23,+18,+17,+15,+100,+101%5D%29%0A&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=9)

But I am having a hard time understanding the time complexity of the whole algorithm. Here is my analysis, and please correct me if I am wrong!

Time Complexity :

> ```
> result = list(islice(it, n)) - > O(n)
>
> heapq.heapify(result) -> O(len(result)) 
>
> for elem in it:
>         _heappushpop(result, elem)  -> I am confused at this part
>
> result.sort(reverse=True) -> O(len(result)*log(len(result)))
> ```

Could anyone help me understand the overall time complexity of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two relevant paramaters here: `n` (the number of items to return), and, say, `M` (the number of items in the dataset).

```
islice(it, n) -- O(n)
heapify(result) -- O(n), because len(result)=n
for elem in it: _heappushpop(result, elem) -- performing M-N times an operation of O(logn), because len(result) remains n, i.e. (M-N)*logn
result.sort(reverse=True) -- O(n*logn)
```

Overall:

```
n + n + (M-n)*logn + n*logn
```

Resulting with `O(M*logn)`.  You can easily see the dominant part is the heappushpop loop (assuming M>>n, otherwise the problem is less interesting, because the solution is more or less reduced to sorting).

---

It is worth pointing out there are l[inear-time algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/251781/2096752) for solving this problem, so if your dataset is very big, it is worth checking them out.

Comment: Why do you say pushpop will take log(n) time ? Can you elaborate this part. Push will take log(n) time and pop will take log(1) time ?

Comment: And what about rearranging after pop?

Comment: @python, I'm not sure what you're asking. Where is there a pop? there's only heappushpop

Comment: Yes so here two operation will be performed right ? Heappush and Heappop?

Comment: `heappushpop` is a special implementation that is faster than a separate call to push and pop. [Here is the source code](https://fossies.org/dox/Python-3.5.0/heapq_8py_source.html), see the helper function "`_siftup`".