# Pseudocode and complexity for ith smallest element in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I have to write an **efficient** pseudocode to find the i-th smallest element in an unsorted array with n elements,where n ,i and A[n] are input data.

In my opinion this means that I have to write the pseudocode for sorting an array in increasing order.I was about to do it with selection sort but I read the question again and it said **efficient** so lets do it with merge sort!

My pseudocode is :

```
    {

    n<---length[A]
    if (n<2)
       return

    mid <--- n/2
    left<---array of size(mid)
    right<---array of size(n- mid)
    for i<---0  to mid-1
    left[i]<--- A[i]
    for i<---mid  to n-1
    right [i-mid]<---A[i]
    Mergesort(left)
    Mergesort(right)
    Merge(left,right,A)
}
```

The complexity in all the cases (worst average best) is O(nlogn).Which means that this algorithm is very fast !

Is my solution correct

Edit: My question is very specific,it asks for an **efficient**  algorithm.Which means we need a fast one.The ones you keep trying to add as duplicate arent efficient they have O(n) complexity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the kth largest element in an unsorted array of length n in O(n)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on)

Comment: Please dont do this to me man,dont downvote the question...there is not a possible answer for me in that thread I have *already*  solved it..

Comment: Isn't O(n) more efficient than O(nlogn)?

Comment: no https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Comment: @JaneD.: It should be clear that `O(n log n)` is asymptotically worse than `O(n)`, since `log n` increases without bounds. That is, for any constant `c`, there is an `n` such that `log n > c`, and consequently `n log n > cn`. I think you are confusing `O(log n)` (fast) with `O(n log n)` (reasonable, but not as fast as `O(n)`)

Comment: @rici So should I just sort this using selection sort?

Comment: @JaneD.: You should not sort at all, or at least not more than necessary. That's why people usually recommend quickselect, which is O(n) if you use median-of-medians to select the pivot, or stochastic O(n) if you use randomized pivots. There is also an algorithm using a priority queue which is `O(n log i)`; in the worst case, where `i == n`,  that's the same as `O(n log n)`, but if you expect `i` to be asymptotically smaller than `n`, it's worth considering.

Comment: And selection sort is awful. Even optimized to not sort the whole vector, it's `O(ni)`.

Comment: I should use linear search to do this so the complexity will be O(1) at best case and O(n) at worst case.I dont know about average case.Linear search  would mean I can only use one for cycle in my pseudocode.How can I use only one cycle in my pseudocode to find the i-th smallest element? :(

Answer (score 0):

**1** Your algorithm is not **very fast.**

With almost any known good standard sort, you can get O(n log n) to sort the entire array. Then take the ith (immediate in an array for example)

**2** Your pseudocode is not finished. what does it return ?

**Some considerations:**

**If i is rather little**, just iterate and keep i minimum datas (insert every new data in a binary tree of the i most little datas, if it is less than the max of these datas). It will take <  O(n) . log i

**If i becomes big**, just sort everything => O (n.log n)

And for further details, see the link already given by sudomakeinstall2:

[How to find the kth largest element in an unsorted array of length n in O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on)