# Efficiently extract row range from SELECT with ORDER BY statement

Tags: sql-server, sorting, range, sql-order-by, row-number

I know that you can use `ROW_NUMER()` to get the row number and then perform `WHERE` on on the results, as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS RowNumber
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
) 
SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, RowNumber  
FROM OrderedOrders 
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 50 AND 60;
```

However, this will first sort all the data and will only then extract the row range.

Since one can find the kth member of a sorted array: [How to find the kth largest element in an unsorted array of length n in O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on), I would hope it would also be possible in SQL.

Comment: it is in SQL Server 2012+

Comment: @Lamak What do you mean? it is if I use the above syntax? what if I do a nested `SELECT` instead of `WITH`?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2420/sql-server-2012-server-side-paging/

Comment: I don't think this is possible in SQL Server (any version) or SQL in general.  You can use `FETCH` along with `ORDER BY` in the outer query, which allows paging (the the use of an index).  But I don't think the algorithm you are referring to is implemented in any database.

Comment: No, you can use [OFFSET](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: `OFFSET` seems perfect. Too bad I need to support pre-2012 :(

Answer (score 0):

The sort can be avoided with an index on OrderDate:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_SalesOrderHeader_OrderDate ON Sales.SalesOrderHeader(OrderDate);
```

An ordered scan of the this index will be performed until the specified upper `ROW_NUMBER()` limit is reached, limiting the scan to that number of rows.  `ROW_NUMBER()` values lower than the specified range will be discarded from the results.

As with any set-based pagination technique in SQL where a useful ordering index exists, performance will largely depend on the number of rows that need to be skipped and returned.

Comment: Well, actually in my case the order by is dynamic and could also contain multiple columns or aggregation values on which I would like to order

Comment: @Mugen, indexes are required to avoid sorting for the `ROW_NUMBER()`.  In the case of computed values, a sort will be required.