# Kth Largest Element in an Array - LeetCode Question

Tags: java, queue

I have been trying to solve [Kth Largest Element in an Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-largest-element-in-an-array/)

This is my code:

```
public static int findKthLargest(int[] nums, int k) {
       Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();
       int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

       for(int i=0; i< nums.length; i++){
           if(nums[i]>=max){
               max = nums[i];
               if(q.size() <k)
                   q.add(max);
               else{
                   q.poll();
                   q.add(max);
               }
           }
       }
       return q.peek();
   }
```

The main idea behind my code is that I keep storing the maximum values in a queue of length K, and after I iterate over all the values in the array I return the first Item as it's the maximium Kth element.

But it fails on the following testcase:
Input: Array = [2, 1]   K = 2
-- Expected output: 1
-- My Output: 2

I just don't get it, how is 1 is supposed to be the 2nd largest element in the array?
Please correct me if I'm messing anything.

Comment: Well, in [2,1] the largest value is 2 and the second largest is 1. Why do you think 2 should be the second largest?

Comment: Checking her output, my guess is she framed her question wrong?

Comment: Btw, your code doesn't make much sense. You're adding new elements as they come until your "queue" has reached a size of `k`. Then you're removing elements from the front if you find larger ones but that's wrong. You'd need to remove the smallest element instead which might be anywhere in that list.

Comment: You'll only enter your if loop once. So you're queue will also only contain 1 element (value 2). You're logic is indeed a bit off I'm afraid.

Comment: You have an array sorted in decrease order (like 5,4,2,1). You get the second entry in the array (the second largest) ([5,4,2,1].get(1) is 4). If there is only two elements in an array (like [2,1]) then the second largets is also the smallest one. Which step in this sequence is unclear?

Comment: The easiest way to get what you want would be to sort the array in descending order and returning the element at index k-1. That would probably not be the fastest variant though otherwise that leetcode task wouldn't be a challenge :)

Comment: Here is an answer of this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just don't get it, how is 1 is supposed to be the 2nd largest element in the array?

If the array consists of just two elements - `1` and `2`, then `2` is the largest, and `1` is the second-largest. It's also the smallest one, but that's unrelated to the question.

You need to think of a better solution to the problem. The current algorithm only inserts into the queue only if you encounter a new "max" element. But what if the first element you get is the biggest one? You'd only enter it into the queue and miss all the others.

Also, why use a queue? Perhaps an ordered collection would be more useful here?