# Return the 6th largest value in a row from Python Datagrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to return the 6th largest row value across 10 columns in a df into a new column, in this case, called "6th_largest". In many of the cases throughout the df there could be more than one row that share the 6th largest value.  It doesn't matter if it's one or several, I only need to return the actual 6th largest value.

A couple of the options from similar questions here have not worked as they are usually specific to the max value (which I have been able to make work) or the 1st and 2nd value only.

```
import pandas as pd

#what the actual df might look like

data_actual = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10]]

df_actual=pd.DataFrame(data_actual, columns=['1st','2nd','3rd','4th','5th','6th',
                                                 '7th','8th','9th','10th'])

#what I want the df to look like after the calculation, returning the 6th largest value.

data_want = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5]]

df_want=pd.DataFrame(data_want, columns=['1st','2nd','3rd','4th','5th','6th',
                                             '7th','8th','9th','10th', '6th Largest'])
```

Comment: I think there are errors in your sample data and expected output. the '5th' column seems to change

Comment: What exactly do you have? Do you already have a dataframe? In general you can simply sort your list and take the sixth value: `tmp_list = my_list.sort() sixth = tmp_list[5]`

Comment: I have a dataframe with 16 million rows or so with 12 columns that I'm trying to assess.  Specifically, I'm looking for the value to be at or above to be in the top half of the responses.


And ALollz, you are correct.  When I went it to edit one of the examples to show that multiple values could be the same I changed the wrong value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, it's easiest to just sort and extract:

```
# np.sort sort increasingly
df['6th Largest'] = np.sort(df.values, axis=1)[:, 4]
```

Comment: `k` largest is not O(n), but `kth` largest is. `k` largest would be O(n*log(k))

Comment: @user3483203 [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on) says it's not just `O(n)`, but rather `O(f(k)n)` for `k` either linear or log. But then again, it's insignificant in this case. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like `introselect`, which is what `np.partition` uses, is a hybrid of the quick select mentioned there.  As far as I am aware introselect is O(n), while quick select is not, but I will admit I haven't looked too much into it.

Comment: This worked perfect on my example but I should have been more precise with how I set the example up.  I have 15 or so columns before the 12 being considered that are all strings.  when I apply np.sort it errors out because of the str's.  Is there a way to repurpose np.sort to manage this or should I rephases the questions and report?

Comment: Something like `df.values[:,0:12]`?

Answer (score 2):

Use, rank:

```
df_actual['6th Largest'] = df_actual.where(df_actual.rank(axis=1) == 6).dropna(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   1st  2nd  3rd  4th  5th  6th  7th  8th  9th  10th  6th Largest
0    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9            5
1    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10            6
```

Comment: `rank` as default does average ranks of equal values. So your answer is incorrect in that case.

Comment: you can use method = min to correct for this occurrence.

Comment: `min` doesn't work either. `0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2` has no rank 6

Comment: There is no sixth value in that series.  Pointless.

Comment: huh? the 6-th largest is `1` isn't it?

Comment: That isn't the sixth largest.  That is still multiple copy of the 2nd largest value.

Comment: Yes, in the example you gave (0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2) I would want '1' returned.

Answer (score 1):

Partition the array since you only care about the `nth` element being in the right place.  This if course assumes you have *at least* `n` elements.

---

```
np.partition(df.to_numpy(), -6, axis=1)[:, -6]
```

```
array([4, 5], dtype=int64)
```

***Timings***

```
In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, (1000, 1000))

In [7]: %timeit np.sort(df.values, axis=1)[:, -6]
38.4 ms ± 1.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit np.partition(df.to_numpy(), -6, axis=1)[:, -6]
8.52 ms ± 191 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Interestingly, this is slower than sort as tested on my system.

Comment: Added some timings, sorts usually end up being faster than optimized algorithms on very small sets of data.

Comment: This is true in general. OP only has 10 columns though :-).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apply` function here:

```
data_actual = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]

df_actual=pd.DataFrame(data_actual, columns=['1st','2nd','3rd','4th','5th','6th',
                                                '7th','8th','9th','10th'])


def get_sixth(row):
    row = row.tolist()
    row.sort()
    return row[5]

df_actual["6th Largest"] = df_actual.apply(get_sixth, axis=1) # axis=1 necessary since you want to get the whole row
print(df_actual)
```

Output:

```
   1st  2nd  3rd  4th  5th  6th  7th  8th  9th  10th  6th Largest
0    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9            5
1    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10            6
```

Comment: `row = row.tolist()` is 1) redundant, `row[5]` works; 2) does not sort the row, so you basically just returns the 5th column.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, must have slipped my mind. WIth the sort `row = row.tolist()` is not redundant anymore