# Compute white and black clip points based on percentages values without sorting

Tags: c, sorting, percentile

In an image processing application, I need to find the black and white clip points to realize a "percent clipping" specified by the user. The pixel values live in an array of length = width x height. The values are double-precision floats.

The straight-forward way is to sort the pixel values from low to high, and then pick the values in the array that are BlackClipPct from the beginning and WhiteClipPct from the end, respectively.

This is what I've implemented, but it's pretty slow for a large image. Is there a way to do this computation without sorting first, or, in general, is there a faster way to do this?

Here's an example, to illustrate.

Imagine a (*sorted*) image array of size 100 that has values {1 2 3 4 .. 97 98 99 100}. If the user wanted to clip 3% on the black end, then I'd set the black point to 3, and if the user wanted to clip 4% on the white end, I'd set the white point to 97, and then do all of the transforms on the data that are quick and straight-forward. The algorithm I need is a quick way to find those two values (3 and 97) **quickly**, which I'm guessing means *without sorting*.

If you could provide something in C that does this, I'd be very very grateful.

Comment: This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on). Algorithms for finding the k-th highest or lowest element in an unordered list are called [selection algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm).

Comment: Except for translating the percentage to a rank (which is trivial) and requesting C code (which exceeds what can be expected on Stack Overflow), this question is a duplicate. You can use the information at the marked original to understand the algorithms and write code, or, knowing the name given to the algorithms, you may use it to search for C code.